# Is $n^{th}$ root of $2$ an irrational number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, rationality-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$a^{1/2}$ is either an integer or an irrational number.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/a1-2-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number)

Will every $n^{th}$ root of $2$ be an irrational number? If yes, how can I prove that?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/a1-2-is-either-an-integer-or-an-irrational-number

Comment: Hint: Fermat's last theorem comes to mind when you want to prove it for n>2. Then proof it for n=2 and you got it.

Comment: In fact $n^{th}$ root of a number, which is not a perfect $n^{th}$ power of an integer, will always be an irrational number.

Comment: @Max: pretty much the worst way to do this problem...

Comment: @Qiaochu: I believe there was a mention of that in the "mosquito-nuking" thread in MO...

Comment: @J.M.: I think FLT for this problem is not "mosquito-nuking" but "bacteria-nuking"

Comment: I think that the most important thing is that the mosquito, bacteria or whatever is dead because of the FLT-nuke.

Comment: @J.M. I rolled back your tag edit (as I did another of your recent edits). Please be careful editing tags in fields for which you may not have expert knowledge.

Comment: Look, @Bill, we're trying to eradicate an exceedingly ambiguous tag here... I can see why you'd add [tag:abstract-algebra], but your removal of [tag:algebra-precalculus] sounds iffy to me. But hey, you're the "expert", good sir.

Comment: Why are people fighting over the tags of a closed question?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783028/how-would-you-prove-that-sqrtn2-is-irrational and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191176/irrationality-of-sqrtn2

Comment: I'm late, but I was just thinking about this.

Answer (score 23):

Yes. In fact, for every integer $k$ and every $n\gt 1$, the $n$th root of $k$ is either an integer or irrational.

One way to prove it is to use exactly the same idea as for proving the square root of $2$ is irrational: suppose $\sqrt[n]{k} =\frac{p}{q}$, with $p$ and $q$ integers, relatively prime. Then $q^nk = p^n$. Now think about the prime factorizations: every prime that divides $q$ must divide $p$, but $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, so $q=1$. That means that you must have $k=p^n$ with $p$ an integer. That is, the only way for the $n$th root of $k$ to be a rational is if $k$ is an $n$th power of an integer.

Or you can use the Rational Root Test: an $n$th root of $k$ is a root of the polynomial $x^n - k$. But a rational root of a polynomial with integer coefficients that is written in lowest term $\frac{p}{q}$ must have denominator $q$ that divides the leading coefficient and numerator $q$ that divides the constant coefficient. So any rational root of $x^n-k$ must be an integer.

Getting this back to your question, since $2$ is not an $n$th power of an integer for any $n\gt 1$, $\sqrt[n]{2}$ is not a rational for any integer $n\gt 1$.

Answer (score 4):

If $\rm\ \sqrt[n] c = a/b,\ \ gcd(a,b) = 1\ $ then $\rm\ c\:\! b^n = a^n \Rightarrow \ b\:|\: a^n.\,$ $\rm\ gcd(a,b) = 1\Rightarrow gcd(a^n,b) = 1\ $ by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/673119/242), so $\,\rm b = 1\ $ hence $\rm\:\ c \  =\ a^n.\, $ In particular $\rm\ c = 2 \Rightarrow\ n = 1.$

There are many possible variations on such irrationality proofs, e.g. using the [Rational Root Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) or directly using Unique Factorization of integers, or using the principality of [denominator ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/if-the-order-divides-a-prime-p-then-the-order-is-p-or-1/4715#4715). Perhaps the most elegant is to employ Dedekind's notion of the [**conductor  ideal**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2883/show-that-3p2q2-implies-3p-and-3q/2941#2941) - which yields a one-line proof that a  $\rm PID$ is integrally closed, i.e. satisfies the monic case of the rational root test.