# How would you prove that $\sqrt[n]{2}$ is irrational?

Tags: radicals, irrational-numbers, rationality-testing

How would you prove that $\sqrt[n]{2}$ is irrational?, where $n \in \{2, 3, 4, \ldots\}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have probably already seen [the proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Square_Root_of_2_is_Irrational) for $n=2$. So, let's assume that $n \geq 3$.

Seeking a contradiction, suppose that $\sqrt[n]{2}$ is rational. This, together with the positivity of $\sqrt[n]{2}$ imply that there exist $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sqrt[n]{2}=p/q$. Raising both sides to the $n^{th}$ power, we see that
$$2=\frac{p^n}{q^n}.$$
Multiplying through by $q^n$ and using $2q^n = q^n + q^n$, we have
$$q^n + q^n = p^n. $$
This violates [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem), giving a contradiction. Thus $\sqrt[n]{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: I wanted to post this as well, saw it last night on 4chan, haha.

Comment: This is very neat.

Answer (score 11):

By the rational root theorem, all rational roots of $x^n - 2$ are one of $\{ \pm 1 , \pm 2 \}$.  It's easy to verify that none of these work if $n \ge 2$.

Comment: It is very neat, but it is not clear that the OP has the rational root theorem at the time this question is asked.

Answer (score 5):

*If* you’re willing to use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, which says that there’s essentially only one way to write an integer as a product of primes, then the proof drops right out.

For, if $2^{1/n}=p/q$ for any integers $p$ and $q$, take the $n$-th power and clear of fractions to get $p^n=2q^n$. How many $2$’s do you see on the left? A number that’s divisible by $n$. How many on the right? A number that’s $1$ more than a multiple of $n$. And there’s your contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly the same way that you prove $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational -- the standard proof generalizes perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that the polynomial 
$$
p(x)=x^{n}-2
$$

is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ using Eisenstein criterion and in
particular it does not have a root in $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Can the downvoter please say what is wrong with this answer ?

Comment: For some reason I had a moment where I thought irreducible $\implies$ no rational root was false, and was too lazy to comment. Sorry. If you'd like to edit your answer I'd be glad to undo the downvote.