# Irrationality of $\sqrt[n]2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, radicals, rationality-testing

I know how to prove the result for $n=2$ by contradiction, but does anyone know a proof for general integers $n$ ?

Thank you for your answers.

Marcus

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose that $\sqrt[n]2$ is rational. Then, for some $p,q\in\mathbb Q$,

$$\sqrt[n]2=\frac{p}{q}\implies 2=\frac{p^n}{q^n}\implies p^n=2q^n=q^n+q^n.$$

Contradiction with Fermat last theorem.

Comment: Damn it.. This is beautiful! Thank you very much :)

Comment: For the sake of completeness could you please briefly remind us of the the proof of Fermat's theorem ?

Comment: I guess the margin is too small ...

Comment: @Nicky. Yeah, exactly: the comment box only allows 600 typographical characters...

Comment: While I love this approach, I'm *certain* FLT depends on the nth root of 2 being irrational in some way

Answer (score 6):

Apply [Eisenstein's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) with $p = 2$ to the polynomial $f(x) = x^n - 2$.  This shows that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, so in particular it has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Nice proof :-) (+1)

Answer (score 5):

FLT is quite a cannon to settle the proof. One can also follow the "classical" approach: assuming WLOG $\gcd(p,q)=1$, if $p^n=2q^n$, then $2 \mid p^n$, implying $2 \mid p$, say $p=2r$. But then $2^{n-1}r^n=q^n$, and since $n \gt 2$, we see that $2 \mid q^n$. It follows that $2 \mid q$, contracting the fact that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime.