# Integer power of fraction never is two

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For any

$$\forall a,b,n \in\mathbb{N}\wedge n\ge 2\Rightarrow\Big(\frac{a}{b}\Big)^{n}\ne 2$$

Here is my proof of it **:**

There are $3$ possibilities:

- $a = b$
- $a > b$
- $b < a$
- $ a = b $ if two numbers are equal, their ratio is $1$ and $1^n$ is always $1$, and $$1 \neq 2$$
- $ a < b $ A smaller number divided by a bigger number is less than one, and a number less than one when raised to integer power can only get smaller, so it cannot be $2$.
- $ a > b $ By taking the $n$-th root on both sides:

$$\frac{a}{b} = \sqrt[n]{2}$$

As the $n$-th sqrt of two can never be expressed as a ratio (Pythagoras proved this I think), this possibility is False too.

---

Is my proof sensible? Is it rigorous? Is it even fully correct? Is the last item of my last too big / complex to be used in something so simple?

I seek any suggestion, improvement or correction.

Comment: Your case analysis is not really relevant, and finally your proof is by stating that someone else proved an equivalent theorem :(

Comment: @YvesDaoust I felt something was wrong about it... if I thought it were good I would not have posted it. :)

Comment: You're basically trying to say that every natural root of $2$ is irrational.

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem reduces the case to $n=2$... Haha

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191176/irrationality-of-sqrtn2

Comment: @YvesDaoust: even worse than that, the theorem cited is usually proved via this result. So one lesson here is that generally speaking you shouldn't use theorems you can't prove.

Comment: @Eoin: exactly. Fermat's last theorem is strong enough to prove that the cube root of 2 is irrational, but too weak to prove the square root is ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Let $$\left(\frac ab\right)^n=2$$ or
$$a^n=2b^n,$$ where $a,b$ have no common factor (otherwise they can be simplified).

The last equation shows that $a^n$ is even. So is $a$, as odd numbers given only odd powers. Then $a^n$ is a multiple of $2^n$ and $a^n/2$ is a multiple of $2^{n-1}$, i.e. is even ($n>1$). Then $b^n$ is even and so is $b$.

$a$ and $b$ are both even, a contradiction.

---

**Second proof**:

Let $a^n=2b^n$, and denote $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the exponents of $2$ in the prime decompositions of $a$ and $b$.

Then as the decomposition is always unique,
$$(2^\alpha\cdot p)^n=2\cdot(2^{\beta}\cdot q)^n$$implies
$$\alpha n=\beta n+1$$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 4):

Note that your proof of the $a>b$ case is all you need as your reasoning applies to the other two cases, so you can certainly shorten the proof.

The fact that you quote is actually a step in the standard proof that $\sqrt[n]2$ is irrational. As such, you should probably prove it from first principles to avoid any circular logic.

Have you seen the proof that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational? Can you adapt this proof to this more general case?

Comment: Pytagoras proof uses the fact that if a and b are coprime so are a^2 and b^2

Comment: @user3105485 exactly. But by the same reasoning, if $a,b$ are coprime, so are $a^n$ and $b^n$ for any $n$.

Comment: this fact seems obvious, shall I prove it or just assume it is true?

Comment: You should prove it if you use it. If $p$ is prime and $p\mid a^n$, then can you show that $p\mid a$? In fact you don't need the full strength of your statement - take a look at Yves's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your  proof  for  the  first  two  cases  are  perfect.

For  the  case  $a>b$  ;  you  could  do  this,in  case  you  do  not  have  the  proof  that  **:**
*$\sqrt[n]{2}$*  *is*  *irrational*  *for*  *$n\ge 2$* (as Mathmo123  says  , is  required)

$$(a/b)^n ={a^n}/{b^n}=2$$
$$or, a^n=2.b^n$$

As  $2$  is  a  prime number ,  this  above  equation  tells  that $2|a$. 
Let  $$a=2k$$ 
 Then  $$2^n.k^n=2.b^n$$
$$2^{n-1}.k^n=b^n$$

Again  this  means $$2|b$$  as  well  so  let  $$b=2j$$
Then  we  get  $$2^{n-1}.k^n=2^n.j^n$$
$$or\ \ \ , k^n=2.j^n$$

The  same  procedure  applied again  shows  that  $$a=2^s\ \ \ and\ \ \ b=2^l\ \ \ for\ \ \ some\ \ \ s,l\in \mathbb N$$

Then  $${(a/b)}^n={({2^s}/{2^l})}^n = (2^{s-l})^n=2^{ns-n}$$

So  this  can  be $2$  iff  $$n(s-l)=2$$

Now  $2$  being  a  prime ,  we  have  $2$  possibilities **:**

- $n=2$,$s-l=1$
- $n=1$,$s-l=2$
  Both  of  them  gives  $$(a/b)^n = 4\neq 2$$  So  we  have  it .Proved .

Answer (score 0):

If $(a/b)^n=2$, then $a^n=2b^n$. We claim that the only integer solution to this equation is when $a=b=0$.

We'll prove this by contradiction. Suppose that there was a non-zero solution $(a,b)$. Choose a solution with minimal value of $|a|+|b|$. Since $2b^n$ is even, it follows that $a^n$ must be even, and therefore $a$ is also even. Now we may write $a=2c$ to obtain that $(2c)^n=2b^n$, so canceling a $2$ from both sides yields $b^n=2^{n-1}c^n$. Therefore $b$ is even, so $b=2d$ for some integer $d$, yielding
$$
2^nd^n=2^{n-1}c^n\implies c^n=2d^n.
$$
Thus we have obtained a solution $(c,d)$ to the original equation which is strictly smaller, in the sense that
$$|c|+|d|=\frac{|a|+|b|}{2}<|a|+|b|.$$

Therefore there is no non-zero integer solution to the equation.