# Prove there is no field of order 4

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I've begun a solution by finding the orders of the elements and finding the relations between them hoping to come to some contradiction.

However I've come across [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42143/can-you-construct-a-field-with-4-elements/), whcih seems to suggest there is a field of order 4? However, I haven't yet covered field extensions. Without field extensions is there no field of order 4?

Comment: There is always a field of order $4$, whether or not you have covered the methods needed to construct it.

Comment: Not understanding the question.  Yes, the field of order $4$ is an extension of the field of order $2$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: The first answer in the linked question tells you how you can find such a field. The second answer gives a general method to construct fields of certain orders.

Comment: To consider fields and field extensions "without field extensions" doesn't make sense. So I don't know what you mean by asking "Without field extensions is there no field of order $4$?"

Comment: Descartes said: "Je pense, donc je suis". In English: "I think, therefore I am". So if he hasn't thought about field extensions before, they don't exist (in his mind), nor the implications of field extensions. So philosophically, they do not exist until you think about them...  I think I can prove about anything philosophically :|

Answer (score 4):

Consider the set $F=\{0,1,a,a+1\}$. Define in it the operations $+$ and $\times$ in the obvious way with the relations
$$x+x=0\;\forall x\in F$$
and
$$a^2=a+1$$
and you have the field.

Answer (score 2):

There always exists a field of order $p^n$.
Consider the roots of the equation $x^{p^n} -x=0$.
The roots of the equation form a field of order $p^n$.
You can clearly see that it has $p^n$ roots from fundamental theorem.and all are distinct.