# How are the integral parts of $(9 + 4\sqrt{5})^n$ and $(9 − 4\sqrt{5})^n$ related to the parity of $n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I am stuck on this question,

> The integral parts of $(9 + 4\sqrt{5})^n$ and $(9 − 4\sqrt{5})^n$ are:
>
> 1. even and zero if $n$ is even;
> 2. odd and zero if $n$ is even;
> 3. even and one if $n$ is even;
> 4. odd and one if $n$ is even.

I think either the problem or the options are wrong. To me it seems that answer should be odd irrespective of $n$. Consider the following:

$$
\begin{align*}
(9 \pm 4 \sqrt{5})^4 &= 51841 \pm 23184\sqrt{5} \\
(9 \pm 4 \sqrt{5})^5 &= 930249 \pm 416020\sqrt{5}
\end{align*}$$

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you are confusing "integral part". You are interpreting it as the value of $a$ if you write $(9\pm 4\sqrt{5})^n = a+b\sqrt{n}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. But what they mean is *the floor* of $(9+4\sqrt{5})^n$, i.e., $\lfloor (9\pm 4\sqrt{5})^n\rfloor$. With that in mind, see Beni Bogosel's answer.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin:Yes,I confused on "integral part".Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The idea is to see that $(9+4\sqrt{5})^n+(9-4\sqrt{5})^n=2d_n$ is an even number for every $n$. This can be seen using the [binomial expansion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), and seeing that odd terms appear once with $+$ once with $-$, and even terms are always with $+$ and integers.

Moreover, $0<(9-4\sqrt{5})=9-\sqrt{80}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{81}+\sqrt{80}}<1$. This means that the integer part of the second term is zero. And for the other one, think as this

$$2d_n-1<(9+4\sqrt{5})^n<2d_n$$ so the integer part of the first term is always odd. The correct answer would be the second one (although this happens for every $n$).

[edit] As Arturo Magidin wrote in his comment, the integer part of a real number 
$x$, often denoted $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the unique integer $\lfloor x \rfloor=k$ such that $k \leq x < k+1$, and it does not equal $a$ from the expansion $(9\pm 4\sqrt{5})^n=a\pm b\sqrt{5},\ a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 11):

Alternative to binomial expansion, we can deduce that $\rm\:w = (9+4\sqrt{5})^n + (9-4\sqrt{5})^n\:$ is even by [noting that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26837/do-odd-imaginary-numbers-exist/26843#26843) the notion of *parity* uniquely extends from $\;\mathbb Z\:$ to $\:\mathbb Z[\sqrt{5}],\:$ where $\rm\:\sqrt{5}\:$ is odd. Conjugating shows  $\rm\:w'= w,\:$ therefore $\rm\:w\in \mathbb Z\,$ with parity $\rm\ {odd}^n\! + {odd}^n = odd+odd = even.\ $ The rest  follows easily from $\,0<9-4\sqrt{5}<1\,$ as Beni explained. Notice, in particular, how this viewpoint is a very *natural* higher-degree extension of ubiquitous parity-based proofs in $\mathbb Z.$

**Alternatively** it follows immediately from the fact that, mod $2$, the sequence $\rm\:w_n\:$ satisfies a monic  integer-coefficient recurrence of order $\,\rm\color{#c00}2\,$ and the first $\,\rm\color{#c00}2\,$ terms are $\equiv 0\pmod{2}.\:$ Hence by induction so are all subsequent terms, i.e. $\rm\ f_{n+2} \equiv\ a\ \color{#0a0}{f_{n+1}} + b\,\color{#0a0}{f_{n}} \equiv\ 0\ $ since by induction $\rm\ \color{#0a0}{f_{n+1},\ f_{n}} \equiv 0.\: $ Equivalently $\rm\:f_n \equiv 0\ $ by the *uniqueness theorem* for solutions of difference equations (recurrences). As I frequently emphasize [uniqueness theorems provide very powerful tools for proving equalities.](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+dubuque+uniqueness+powerful+tools)

Worth emphasis: for difference (vs. differential) equations, the uniqueness theorem is trivial, amounting to an obvious induction that if two solutions of an order $\rm\:d\:$ monic integer coefficient recurrence agree for $\rm\:d\:$ initial values then they agree at all subsequent values; equivalently, taking differences, if a solution is $\:0\:$ for $\rm\:d\:$ initial values then it is identically $\,0.\,$ The induction step simply employs the recurrence to lift up the equality from the prior $\rm\,d\,$ values - as above for $\rm\,d=2.$

More generally the same holds true for integer-linear combinations of roots of any monic integer coefficient equation (i.e. algebraic integer roots) since they too will satisfy a monic integer coefficient recurrence, viz. the *characteristic equation* associated to the polynomial having said roots (the quadratic case is the widely studied [Lucas sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89149/242)). Thus every term of the sequence will be divisible by $\rm\:m\:$ iff it is true for the first $\rm\:d\:$ (= order) terms.  More generally it is [easy to prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4185651/242) that the gcd of all terms is simply the gcd of the initial values.

Note that, as above, one requires only the knowledge of the *existence* of such a recurrence. There is no need to explicitly calculate the coefficients of the recurrence; rather, only its order is employed.

Answer (score 6):

To prove that 
$$
a_n:=\left(9+4\sqrt5\right)^n+\left(9-4\sqrt5\right)^n
$$ 
is an even integer, it suffices to observe that $a_0=2,a_1=18$ and 
$$
a_{n+2}=18\ a_{n+1}-a_n
$$
for $n\ge0$.

**Variation**.

Note that $a_n$ is an integer. Indeed $a_n$ is of the form $b_n+c_n\sqrt5$ with $b_n,c_n$ integers, and $a_n$ doesn't depend on the choice of the square root of $5$, so $c_n=0$.

Once we know that $a_n$ is an integer, we can compute it in the field $\mathbb F_2$ with two elements (in which $\sqrt5$ exists).

**EDIT.** The above arguments show this: If $a,b,d,n$ are integers, and if $n\ge0$, then 
$$
\left(a+b\sqrt d\right)^n+\left(a-b\sqrt d\right)^n
$$
is an even integer.

Comment: The recursion comes from the quadratic equation that defines $9 \pm 4 \sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Dear @lhf: Yes, the minimal polynomial is $X^2-\tau\ X+\nu$, where $\tau$ is the trace and $\nu$ the norm.