# Prove $x = \sqrt[100]{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}} + \sqrt[100]{\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}}$ is irrational

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

Prove $x = \sqrt[100]{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}} + \sqrt[100]{\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}}$ is irrational.

I can prove that $x$ is irrational by showing that it's a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients and use rational root theorem to deduce it must be either irrational or an integer and then show it's not an integer, therefore, it must be irrational.

I was wondering what are the other methods to prove $x$ is irrational. I'd be very interested in seeing alternative proofs.

Comment: It's not an answer, but to be honest it's the only proof I could come up with.

Comment: There's a direct proof assuming the freshman's dream. `:-)`

Comment: Your method is fine. The hard part seems to be proving that $x$ is not an integer. How do you do that without evaluating $x$? BTW, $x$ is almost an integer: $x \approx 2.00013$.

Comment: What polynomial do you think it is not a root of?

Comment: @lhf: It is easy to prove $x$ is not an integer: since $0\lt \sqrt{2} \lt \sqrt{3} \lt 2^{99}$ you can find  $0 \lt \sqrt[100]{\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}} \lt 1 \lt \sqrt[100]{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}} \lt 2$ so $1 \lt x \lt 3$ leaving perhaps the possibility $x=2$.  But $x=y + 1/y$ where $y=\sqrt[100]{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}}$, and the only solution of $2=y + 1/y$ is $y=1$ while $\sqrt[100]{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}} \not= 1$.

Comment: Related, but different: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404139 ; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951609/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let $y = \sqrt[100]{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}}$. Then $x = y + {1 \over y}$. Suppose $x$ were some rational number $q$. Then $y^2 - qy  + 1 = 0$. This means ${\mathbb Q}(y)$ is a field extension of ${\mathbb Q}$ of degree two, and every rational function of $y$ is in this field extension. This includes $y^{100} = \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}$, and $y^{-100} = \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}$. So their sum and difference is also in ${\mathbb Q}(y)$. Hence ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) \subset {\mathbb Q}(y)$. But ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is an extension of ${\mathbb Q}$ of degree 4, a contradiction.

You can make the above more elementary by showing successive powers of $y$ are always of the form $q_1y + q_2$ with $q_1$ and $q_2$ rational and eventually showing some $q_3\sqrt{2} + q_4\sqrt{3}$ must be rational, a contradiction.

Answer (score 22):

Note $\ \ \color{#c00}{\alpha+\bar\alpha,\ \alpha\:\!\bar\alpha}\in\Bbb Q\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#0a0}{\alpha^{n}+\bar\alpha^{\:\!n}}\in \Bbb Q\ $ for all $\,n\in\Bbb N\,$ by induction, [since](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/678917/242)

$$ \alpha^{n+1}+\bar\alpha^{\:\!n+1} = (\color{#c00}{\alpha+\bar\alpha})\ (\alpha^n+\bar\alpha^{\:\!n})-\color{#c00}{\alpha\:\!\bar\alpha}\, (\alpha^{n-1}+\bar\alpha^{\:\!n-1})\quad$$

$\begin{align}\alpha = \sqrt[100]{\sqrt3+\!\sqrt2}\\ 
            \bar\alpha = \sqrt[100]{\sqrt3-\!\sqrt2}\end{align}$ $\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{\alpha\:\!\bar\alpha} = 1\in\Bbb Q\ $ so $\, \color{#c00}{\alpha + \bar\alpha}\in\Bbb Q\,\Rightarrow\,2\sqrt{3} = \color{#0a0}{\alpha^{100} + \bar\alpha^{100}} \in\mathbb Q\, \Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$

**Generally** $\,\alpha+\bar\alpha,\,\alpha\:\!\bar\alpha\in\Bbb Q\Rightarrow f(\alpha,\bar \alpha)\in \Bbb Q\,$ for any *symmetric* polynomial $f(x,y)\in\Bbb Q[x,y]\,$ since such a polynomial [can be written](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2386884/242) as a polynomial in $\,\alpha+\bar\alpha,\ \alpha\:\!\bar\alpha\,$ with integer coefficients [(Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Polynomials)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials). Above $\,f(x,y) = x^{100}+y^{100}$.

Look up *Lucas-Lehmer* sequences to learn more about such power sums of algebraic numbers.

Answer (score 18):

If $y + y^{-1} = x$, then $y^n + y^{-n}$ is a polynomial $F_n(x)$ with integer
coefficients in $x$. 
In particular, if $x$ is rational, then so is: 
$$F_{100}(x) = y^{100} + y^{-100} = (\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}) + (\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}) 
=2 \sqrt{3}.$$

The polynomials $F_{n}(x)$ are (up to scaling and renormalization) the
Chebyshev polynomials. One has $F_0(x) = 2$, $F_1(x) = x$, $F_2(x) = x^2 - 2$,
and $F_{n}(x) = x F_{n-1}(x) - F_{n-2}(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

We first claim that:
$$x = a^{1/5} + a^{-1/5} \in \mathbb{Q} \implies a + a^{-1} \in \mathbb{Q}$$
To prove this we use some clever manipulation to find:
$$(a^{1/5} + a^{-1/5})^5 = a + a^{-1} + 5(a^{1/5} + a^{-1/5})^3 - 5(a^{1/5} + a^{-1/5})$$
$$a + a^{-1} = x^5 - 5x^3 +5x \in \mathbb{Q}$$
Similiarly, we prove:
$$x = a^{1/2} + a^{-1/2} \in \mathbb{Q} \implies a + a^{-1} \in \mathbb{Q}$$
Then if we let: $$a = \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}$$
and assume that:
$$x = \sqrt[100]{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}} + \sqrt[100]{\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}} \in \mathbb{Q}$$
we have:
$$ x \in \mathbb{Q} \implies a^{1/100} + a^{-1/100} \in \mathbb{Q}$$
$$\implies a^{1/50} + a^{-1/50} \in \mathbb{Q} \implies a^{1/25} + a^{-1/25} \in \mathbb{Q}$$
$$\implies a^{1/5} + a^{-1/5} \in \mathbb{Q} \implies a + a^{-1} \in \mathbb{Q} \implies 2\sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}$$
So, by contradiction:
$$\sqrt[100]{\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2}} + \sqrt[100]{\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}} \notin \mathbb{Q}$$