# Why is $\sqrt[3]{18+5\sqrt{13}} + \sqrt[3]{18-5\sqrt{13}} = 3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, factoring, substitution, nested-radicals

> How to show that $$\sqrt[3]{18+5\sqrt{13}} + \sqrt[3]{18-5\sqrt{13}} = 3?$$

This equality comes from solving $$t^3 - 15 t - 4 = 0$$ using [Cardanos fomula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_Formula]) and knowing the solution $t_1=4$.

I have attempted multiplying the whole thing with $(\sqrt[3]{18+5\sqrt{13}})^2 - (\sqrt[3]{18-5\sqrt{13}})^2$, but no success. Then I have solved for one cubic root and put all to the third power. Also no success.

Comment: The "trick" $(a+b)(a-b) = a^2-b^2$ that works for square roots will not work for cube roots. Maybe you want to think about the analogous formula $(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2) = a^3+b^3$.

Comment: @TedShifrin you appear here but not in chat ;_;

Comment: The other two solutions to the equation are $-2\pm\sqrt{3}$, so this is perhaps some clever use of Vieta's formulas.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89067

Comment: The more recent question [How to prove that $(-18+\sqrt{325})^{\frac{1}{3}}+(-18-\sqrt{325})^{\frac{1}{3}} = 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3011230) is very, very nearly a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $(a + b\sqrt{13})^3 = (18 + 5\sqrt{13})$ for $a, b \in \Bbb Q$

Expanding the LHS gives,

$$(a^3 + 39 ab^2 - 18 ) +\sqrt{13}(3a^2 b + 13 b^3 - 5) = 0$$,

From this we get,

$$\begin{cases}a^3 + 39 ab^2 - 18 = 0 \\ 3a^2 b + 13 b^3 - 5 = 0\end{cases}$$

Solving the system give $ a = \dfrac 32$ and $ b = \dfrac12$

Therefore

$$\sqrt[3]{(18 + 5\sqrt{13})} = \dfrac 32 +\dfrac12\sqrt{13}$$

Similarly,

$$\sqrt[3]{(18 - 5\sqrt{13})} = \dfrac 32 -\dfrac12\sqrt{13}$$

Hence the sum is $3$.

Comment: Thats very nice!

Comment: @R_Berger My reaction when I first learnt this trick.

Comment: That gives some idea on field extensions, and contains in deed potential to generalization, I think.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I don't doubt that it is a bit ugly . I outlined the general method which OP can  use elsewhere, for instance  when he does not know the sum beforehand or when he had to denest radicals. No doubt your method is a bit easy here and I had +1 on your answer anyways.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg No problem. Cheers :).

Comment: May I know how did you solve the system? By solving a cubic equation or some other way?

Comment: @user486600 I used rational root theorem.

Comment: That is, you've arrived to a cubic equation and then have used the rational root theorem?

Comment: @user486600 Yes, I checked 3 or 4 numbers by hand and got $b^3 = 1/8$, I was lucky I guess.

Comment: @123 Thanks....

Comment: @user486600 Welcome :).

Answer (score 5):

Hint :$$a=\sqrt[3]{18+5\sqrt{13}} + \sqrt[3]{18-5\sqrt{13}}=b+c \\a^3=b^3+c^3+3bc(b+c)\\
a^3=18+5\sqrt{13}+18-5\sqrt{13}+3\sqrt[3]{18+5\sqrt{13}}.\sqrt[3]{18-5\sqrt{13}}(a)\\a^3=36+3\sqrt[3]{324-325}a\\a^3=36-3a$$solve for a 
$$a^3+3a-36=(a-3)(a^2+3a+12)=0 \to a=3$$

Comment: If you remove the dot (its less than 6 char edit) then its the answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$\left(\sqrt[3]{18+5\sqrt{13}} + \sqrt[3]{18-5\sqrt{13}}\right)^3=$$
$$=18+5\sqrt{13}+18-5\sqrt{13}+3\sqrt[3]{18+5\sqrt{13}} \sqrt[3]{18-5\sqrt{13}}\left(\sqrt[3]{18+5\sqrt{13}} + \sqrt[3]{18-5\sqrt{13}}\right)=$$
$$=36+3\sqrt[3]{-1}\left(\sqrt[3]{18+5\sqrt{13}} + \sqrt[3]{18-5\sqrt{13}}\right)=$$
$$=36-3\left(\sqrt[3]{18+5\sqrt{13}} + \sqrt[3]{18-5\sqrt{13}}\right).$$
Now, let $\sqrt[3]{18+5\sqrt{13}} + \sqrt[3]{18-5\sqrt{13}}=x.$

Thus, $$x^3=36-3x$$ or
$$x^3-3x^2+3x^2-9x+12x-36=0$$ or
$$(x-3)(x^2+3x+12)=0,$$ which gives $x=3$.

But I think the best way in this formulation it's the way by using
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc).$$
Now, we need to prove that
$$18+5\sqrt{13}+18-5\sqrt{13}-27-3\cdot(-3)\sqrt[3]{18+5\sqrt{13}}\cdot\sqrt[3]{18-5\sqrt{13}}=0$$ or
$$36-27-3(-3)(-1)=0,$$
which is true.

Done!

Comment: You mean cubing?

Comment: Thanks guys! I fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Because the function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto x^3$ is injective, it follows that

$x = y \iff x^3 = y^3$ (more precicely: $\Leftarrow$ follows from injectivity)

So, you can cube both sides without any danger, calculate, and make the conclusion you are looking for.

Comment: In the square case, I would have taken the danger on me.

Comment: Seems like we have a real badass here :P