# $\lfloor (2+\sqrt{3})^n \rfloor $ is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions, parity

> Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer. Show that $\lfloor (2+\sqrt{3})^n \rfloor $ is odd and that $2^{n+1}$ divides $\lfloor (1+\sqrt{3})^{2n} \rfloor+1 $.

My attempt:

$$ u_{n}=(2+\sqrt{3})^n+(2-\sqrt{3})^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}2^{n-k}(3^{k/2}+(-1)^k3^{k/2})\in\mathbb{2N} $$

$$ 0\leq (2-\sqrt{3})^n \leq1$$

$$ (2+\sqrt{3})^n\leq u_{n}\leq 1+(2+\sqrt{3})^n $$

$$ (2+\sqrt{3})^n-1\leq u_{n}-1\leq (2+\sqrt{3})^n $$

$$ \lfloor (2+\sqrt{3})^n \rfloor=u_{n}-1\in\mathbb{2N}+1 $$

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48508/how-are-the-integral-parts-of-9-4-sqrt5n-and-9-4-sqrt5n-relate

Comment: What do you mean by "integer part"? The floor function, or the first coordinate with respect to the basis $(1,\sqrt 3)$ of the $\Bbb Z$-module $\Bbb Z[\sqrt3]$?

Comment: Because the latter is even for $n=1$. On the other hand, I don't see what having some $2$ on the RHS has to do with evaluating the floor function of that sum of irrational numbers (for instance, the last term of the sum on the RHS would be $\binom nn2^{n-n}3^{n/2}=1\cdot 1\cdot \sqrt{3^n}$ )

Comment: The reason GaeS is asking is because your proof seems to be either evaluating or ignoring the “evenness” of terms that are clearly irrational.  If you were concerned with the floor function this would be unjustified.

Comment: If the interpretation were the first coordinate with respect to the basis $(1, \sqrt{3})$ then the statement would be false: for example, $(2+\sqrt{3})^1 = 2+\sqrt{3}$ and $(2+\sqrt{3})^3 = 26 + 15\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Hint (with the interpretation of "integer part" being the floor function): examine the sequence $a_n = (2+\sqrt{3})^n + (2-\sqrt{3})^n$.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3167229/even-number-binomial)

Comment: Use `\binom nk` or `\binom{n}{k}` or `{n \choose k}` instead of `C^k_n`

Comment: for example, in $a + \sqrt {b}$, the question wants to prove that a is odd

Comment: FWIW I'd intepret the "integer part" to mean if $(2+\sqrt 3)^k -1= a + b\sqrt 3$ then the "integer part" is $a$.  As $(2+\sqrt 3)^2 - 1= (4 + 4\sqrt 3 + 3) -1 = 6+4\sqrt 3$ I'd say it is false.

Comment: But it is the integer part of $(2+\sqrt{3})^k$, you add "1" to the end

Comment: But it is the integer part of $(2+\sqrt{3})^k$, you add "1" to the end

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not hard to prove that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\left(2+\sqrt3\right)^n+\left(2-\sqrt3\right)^n\in2\mathbb N.$$This, together with the fact that $2-\sqrt3\in(0,1),$ is enough to prove that $\left\lfloor\left(2+\sqrt3\right)^n\right\rfloor$ is an odd integer.

Answer (score 15):

*Hint for the first part:* Consider $u_n = (2+\sqrt{3})^{n} + (2-\sqrt{3})^{n}$. Prove that $u_n$ is always an even integer and that $u_n = \lceil (2+\sqrt{3})^n \rceil$. Use that $(2-\sqrt{3})^{n}\to 0$.

(This has now been incorporated into the edited question.)

*Hint for the second part:* Consider $v_n = (1+\sqrt{3})^{n} + (1-\sqrt{3})^{n}$. Find a second-order recursion for $v_n$ based on the quadratic equation that defines $1\pm\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: You don't really need $(2-\sqrt 3)^n\to 0$, just that $0<(2-\sqrt 3)^n<1$, right?  And you've confused $u_n$ and $u_2n$ in the second part.

Comment: @Thomas, right, just that $0<(2-\sqrt 3)^n<1$. I've fixed the typo, thanks.

Comment: Could someone detail the second part?

Comment: @PlaneChon-Ju, actually, I don't think that the second part is true. The numbers in the sequence are 2,4,14,52,194,724,2702,10084,37634,140452,524174,1956244,7300802,27246964 and they are either 2 or 4 times an odd number.

Comment: Sorry, the quantity is actually $\lfloor (1+\sqrt{3})^{2n} \rfloor+1 $

Comment: @PlaneChon-Ju, after so many edits I think it's best if you asked a separate question. But the answers here should give you enough to start.

Answer (score 6):

You can use recurrences such as $$f(n)=4f(n-1)-f(n-2)+2$$ or $$f(n)=5f(n-1)-5f(n-2)+f(n-3)$$ starting at $f(0)=1, f(1)=3$.

Then show the various results by induction.

Answer (score 2):

*For the first claim:*

Here is a more general discussion.
As is often the case,
none of this is original,
and I did work it out
on my own for fun.

To make one root of
$f(x)
=x^2-2ax+b
=0$
with
$a, b > 0$
in $(0, 1)$.

The roots are
$x_{\pm}
=\dfrac{2a\pm\sqrt{4a^2-4b}}{2}
=a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
x_{-}
&=a-\sqrt{a^2-b}\\
&=(a-\sqrt{a^2-b})\dfrac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}\\
&=\dfrac{a^2-(a^2-b)}{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}\\
&=\dfrac{b}{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}\\
\end{array}
$

So we want
$0 < b < a+\sqrt{a^2-b}
$
so that
$ b < a^2$
and
$(b-a)^2 < a^2-b
$
or
$b^2-2ab+a^2 < a^2-b
$
or
$b^2+b < 2ab
$
or
$b< 2a-1$.

If $a=2$ then
$b < 3$
so, if $b$ is an integer,
$b \in \{1, 2\}
$
so
$a^2-b
\in \{3, 2\}
$
so
$\{x_-, x_+\}
=2\pm\sqrt{3},
2\pm\sqrt{2}
$.

Let $c = a^2-b$.

$\begin{array}\\
x_+^n+x_-^n
&=(a+\sqrt{c})^n+(a-\sqrt{c})^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^kc^{(n-k)/2}+\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^k(-1)^{n-k}c^{(n-k)/2}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^kc^{(n-k)/2}(1+(-1)^{n-k})\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}c^{k/2}(1+(-1)^{k})\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}2\binom{n}{2k}a^{n-2k}c^{k}\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}a^{n-2k}c^{k}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$0 < x_-^n < 1$.
$\lfloor x_+^n-1 \rfloor
$
is odd and
$\lfloor x_+^n\rfloor
=2\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}a^{n-2k}c^{k}-1
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
x_+^n-\lfloor x_+^n \rfloor
&=x_+^n-2\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}a^{n-2k}c^{k}+1\\
&=1-x_-^n\\
&\to_- 1\\
\end{array}
$

If $a=2, b=1$
then
$x_+^n-\lfloor x_+^n \rfloor
=1-(2-\sqrt{3})^n
=1-\dfrac{1}{(2+\sqrt{3})^n}
$.