# Does the series $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \sin((1+\sqrt{2})^n\pi)$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying the following exercise,

> Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \sin((1+\sqrt{2})^n\pi)$

I tried like the method for $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}  \sin((2+\sqrt{3})^n\pi)$,

with $u_n=\sin((1-\sqrt{2})^n\pi)$ unfortunately $(1-\sqrt{2})<0$ so I cannot use theorem for positivness.

There is an another trick for this one ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean $+$ or $-$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(\pi(2+\sqrt{3})^n)$ converge? Converge absolutely?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97548/does-sum-n-1-infty-sin-pi2-sqrt3n-converge-converge-absolutely)

Comment: @Nemo: that series does not alternate, so there is a bit more to do for this series. I wouldn't call it even an abstract duplicate. The OP even mentions that series in their question, so the answers to that question do not seem to answer this question to them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $b_n=(1+\sqrt{2})^n +(1-\sqrt{2})^n$.  Then $b_n$ is an **integer**. (As pointed out by Aaron, that can be seen by expanding, using the Binomial Theorem, and noting the cancellations. It can also be seen by noting that the expression for $b_n$ is invariant under the mapping that takes $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$.)

So $\pi(1+\sqrt{2})^n$ differs from $\pi b_n$ ($\pi$ times an integer) by $\pi(1-\sqrt{2})^n$. Note that if $n$ is large, then the absolute value of $\pi(1-\sqrt{2})^n$ is very close to $0$.

The $n$-th term of our series has absolute value $|\sin(\pi(1-\sqrt{2})^n)|$, which is less than $\pi(\sqrt{2}-1)^n$.

But $\sum \pi(\sqrt{2}-1)^n$ converges, since it is a geometric series with common ratio $\lt 1$. Thus by Comparison the series of the problem converges absolutely, and hence converges.

**Remark:** Whenever $1+\sqrt{2}$ has a problem, its buddy $1-\sqrt{2}$ is ready to help.

Comment: Note that the assertion in the first sentence can be seen by expanding both powers using the binomial theorem and noting that the terms with odd powers of $\sqrt{2}$ cancel out.

Comment: Of course, I forgot to factorize my series to get a geometric series. Thanks

Comment: (What did you mean by the expression is invariant under the mapping ?)

Comment: Another way to prove that $u_n := (1+\sqrt{2})^n+(1-\sqrt{2})^n$ is an integer comes from the fact that $(1+\sqrt{2})$ and $(1-\sqrt{2})$ are conjugated quadratics : they are both roots of the polynomial $x^2-2x-1$. Hence, it can be shown that $u_{n+2} = 2u_{n+1}+u_n$, and $u_0 = u_1 = 2$, from where a trivial reccurence shows that $u_n$ is always an integer.

Comment: Elaborating on the invariance, the expression clearly lies in the field $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$, and being invariant under the conjugation means (by basic galois theory) that the expression is rational.  However, it is also an algebraic integer (being a sum of powers of algebraic integers), and every rational algebraic integer is in fact an integer.

Comment: If everywhere in $(1+\sqrt{2})^n +(1-\sqrt{2})^n$ we replace $\sqrt{2}$ by $-\sqrt{2}$, the two terms get interchanged, but the sum does not change.

Comment: @D.Thomine And you can do like this for several series too..like $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, André Nicolas thanks!

Comment: It seems important to note that $\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^n+\left(1-\sqrt2\right)^n$ is an **even** integer since that makes it possible to say $\sin\left(\left(1+\sqrt2\right)^n\pi\right)=(-1)^{n+1}\sin\left(\left(\sqrt2-1\right)^n\pi\right)$