# Proof that [(1 + √3) ²ⁿ⁺¹] is divisible by 2ⁿ⁺¹ ( [x] denotes the greatest integer function of x) for n >= 0

Tags: number-theory, functions, exponential-function, integers, step-function

I came up with a proof but I am not sure if that is correct.
I am not sure whether this is rigorous proof, but I think I have a proof for the fact that $[(1 + \sqrt{3})^{2n+1}] = k2^{n+1}$ for $k \in N$. 

It is primarily based on the idea that $2 = (\sqrt{3} - 1) (\sqrt{3} + 1)$

So, it goes something like this:

In order to prove that, [$(1 + \sqrt{3})^{2n+1}] = k2^{n+1}$

We need to prove that,

$k2^{n+1} \le (1 + \sqrt{3})^{2n+1} < k2^{n+1} + 1$

Which same as proving,

$k((\sqrt(3) - 1)(\sqrt(3) + 1))^{n+1} \le (1 + \sqrt{3})^{2n+1} < k((\sqrt(3) - 1)(\sqrt(3) + 1))^{n+1} + 1$

Which is same as proving,

$k(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1} \le (1 + \sqrt{3})^{n} < k(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1} + \frac{1}{(1 + \sqrt{3})^{n + 1}}$

Which is same as proving,

$[(1 + \sqrt{3})^{n}] = [k(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1}]$ or $[(1 + \sqrt{3})^{n}] = [k(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1}] + 1$

Because $\frac{1}{(1 + \sqrt{3})^{n + 1}} < 1$ as $n \ge 0$

What does proving $[(1 + \sqrt{3})^{n}] = [k(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1}]$ really mean ?

I think it means (and I may be wrong) that we can always find such a $k$ for any given $n$

From the equation $[(1 + \sqrt{3})^{n}] = [k(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1}]$ , it looks very obvious that such a k should always exist.

Just to add more rigor let’s assume that,
$[(1 + \sqrt{3})^{n}] = p$
where $p \in N$

So this reduces to finding a $k$ such that $[k(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1}] = p$
which means $p \le k(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1} < p + 1$

Consider the first half of the inequality

$p \le k(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1} $

$\frac{p}{(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1}} \le k$

$\frac{p(\sqrt(3) + 1)^{n + 1}}{2^{n+1}} \le k$ $.... (1)$

Clearly for any given natural number $p$ we can always find such a positive integer $k$

Let’s consider the other half of the inequality,

$k(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1} < p + 1$

$k < \frac{p + 1}{(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1}}$

$k < \frac{(p + 1)(\sqrt(3) + 1)^{n + 1}}{2^{n+1}}$ $.... (2)$

Clearly a positive integer satisfying both (1) and (2) will always exist because,

$\frac{(p + 1)(\sqrt(3) + 1)^{n}}{2^{n+1}} - \frac{(p)(\sqrt(3) + 1)^{n}}{2^{n+1}} = \frac{(\sqrt(3) + 1)^{n + 1}}{2^{n+1}}( p + 1 - p) = \frac{(\sqrt(3) + 1)^{n + 1}}{2^{n+1}}$
and $\frac{(\sqrt(3) + 1)^{n + 1}}{2^{n+1}} > 1$ and hence $k$ always exists.

What does this prove ?? Well since every step in the above derivation is reversible I guess we can conclude that $[(1 + \sqrt{3})^{2n+1}] $is divisible by $2^{n+1}$

Similarly we can also prove that $[(1 + \sqrt{3})^{n}] = [k(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1}] + 1$ will also always have a solution, by assuming $[(1 + \sqrt{3})^{n}] - 1 = p$

P.S : I will be thankful if someone reviews my proof :)

Comment: You showed that you can find $k$ such that 
$$
[(1 + \sqrt{3})^{n}] = [k(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1}],
$$
and you can also find $k$ such that
$$
[(1 + \sqrt{3})^{n}] = [k(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1}]+1.
$$
But neither of this directly implies 
$$
k(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1} \le (1 + \sqrt{3})^{n} < k(\sqrt(3) - 1)^{n+1} + \frac{1}{(1 + \sqrt{3})^{n + 1}}.
$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127893/showing-that-lceil-sqrt3-12n-rceil-is-divisible-by-2n1  and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202564/product-of-integral-and-fractional-part-of-binomial-expansion