# Generalized definition of parity

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was reading 'Mathematical circles' and it used parity to solve a lot of questions. I was curious that, is there a standard definition of parity over rational numbers or maybe real numbers?

Comment: By 'standard definition' do you mean accepted "universally accepted by mathematicians", or "most common extension"?

Comment: A widely accepted definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of *parity* can be extended to many rings - but certainly not all rings, since 
if $\,2\,$ has an inverse $\,u\,$ then $\,2u = 1\ \Rightarrow 2\mid 1\mid x\,$ so everything is "even". So we can't extend it to *all* rationals, but if we restrict to the subring of rationals with *odd* denominator then integer parity has a unique extension: the parity of $\,m/(2n+1)\,$ is the parity of $\,m,\,$ by $\bmod 2\!:\ (2n+1)^{-1}\equiv 1^{-1}\equiv 1.\,$

More generally we can always apply parity arguments in any ring which has $\,\Bbb Z/2 = $ integers $\!\bmod 2\,$ as a homomorphic image, e.g. the Gaussian integers $\,\mathbb Z[i],\,$ where the image $\ \mathbb Z[i]/(2,i\!-\!1) \cong \mathbb Z/2\ $ yields the natural parity definition that $\ a+b\,i\ $ is even $\iff a\equiv b\pmod{\! 2}\ $, i.e. if $\ a+b\,i\ $ maps to $\,0\,$ via the above isomorphism, which maps $\ 2\to 0,\ i\to 1\,$.

Similar ideas work for many rings of algebraic integers (though parity need not exist nor be unique in general). See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26843/242) for further discussion. See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48533/242) which uses parity in $\,\mathbb Z[\sqrt{5}]\,$ to show  the integer $\,(9+4\sqrt{5})^n + (9-4\sqrt{5})^n\,$ is even, and see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49039/242) for parity in an ordered ring with *infinite* elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard definition of parity for rational numbers. You can look at the power of $2$ that appears when you write a nonzero rational number in lowest terms. That function is usually written as $\nu_2$, so for example
$$
\begin{align}
\nu_2(8) &= 3 \\
\nu_2(24) &= 3 \\
\nu_2(5/8) &= -3 \\
\nu_2(5/3) &= 0 \\
\end{align}
$$
Then a nonzero integer $n$ is even just when $\nu_2(n) > 0$.

You can generalize by defining $\nu_p$ for any prime $p$.

There's no good way to do any of this for real numbers.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a name for this function?

Comment: I think it does have a name, but I don't know it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number

Comment: The article linked by @EthanBolker calls it a $p$-adic valuation, and I seemed to see that name in another place too.