# induction method for sqrt

Tags: induction

$$(1+\sqrt 2)^n-(1-\sqrt2)^n=b_n\sqrt2$$
$$n\in N $$ $$b_n\in N$$
I needed to solve this by the induction method.
The base and thesis of induction is easy, is to substitute n for n + 1, but I can not reduce the expression, someone could give an aid

Comment: It is not clear to me what you're trying to do. What is $B_n$?

Comment: prove by induction the question, B is any natural number, at least that's what I understood from the exercise

Comment: We need a condition by $b_{n}$ I guess

Comment: @Monica So you have to prove that $b_n\in \mathbb N$?

Comment: this is given in the exercise, I have to prove by induction that the function is true, for n = 0 it works

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3169526/deduce-that-the-next-integer-greater-than-3-sqrt5n-is-divisible-by-2n/3169544#3169544

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: @Monica: I've written a more complete answer, but I've removed some of it until more context is provided.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I really want to learn, but there are more difficult subjects than others

Comment: @Monica: you have already stated that this is an exercise, yet you have shown no effort. This site is not here to do your homework for you. We are willing to help once you have shown some effort. Please add some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960).

Answer (score 1):

Just write
$(1+\sqrt{2})^{n+1} = (1+\sqrt{2})(1+\sqrt{2})^n$

You can then develop, while keeping the part which is to the $n$, for the induction. Do that on the other term also, and it should work

Comment: it would be possible to develop the answer, I was blocked

Answer (score 1):

Since $\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^2=3+2\sqrt{2}$, and $\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^2=3-2\sqrt{2}$, it is not too difficult to see that both $1+\sqrt{2}$ and $1-\sqrt{2}$ satisfy
$$
x^2=2x+1\tag1
$$
This can be used to get a recurrence for $b_n$.

Comment: but this way I can not prove by induction, since it is necessary that one of the parcels gives the other

Comment: Once you have a recurrence for $b_n$ and show that some initial values are integers, you can show **by induction** that all are integers.

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier to prove *two* statements.

That $(1 + \sqrt 2)^n - (1-\sqrt 2)^n = b_n \sqrt 2$

And $(1 + \sqrt 2)^n + (1 - \sqrt 2)^n = c_n$. where $b_n, c_n$ are integers.

Base cases:

For $n =1$ then $(1 + \sqrt 2)-(1-\sqrt 2) = 2\sqrt 2$ and $(1+\sqrt 2)+(1-\sqrt 2)=2$.

Induction cases:

If $(1 + \sqrt 2)^n -(1-\sqrt 2)^n = b_n \sqrt 2$ and $(1 + \sqrt 2)^n +(1-\sqrt 2)^n=c_n$

Then $(1 + \sqrt 2)^{n+1} - (1 - \sqrt 2)^{n+1} = $

$(1 + \sqrt 2)^n(1 + \sqrt 2) - (1 - \sqrt 2)^n(1 - \sqrt 2) =$

$(1 + \sqrt 2)^n + \sqrt 2(1+ \sqrt 2)^n - (1-\sqrt 2)^n + (1-\sqrt 2)^n\sqrt 2 =$

$(1 + \sqrt 2)^n  - (1-\sqrt 2)^n + \sqrt 2(1+ \sqrt 2)^n+ (1-\sqrt 2)^n\sqrt 2 =$

$b_n \sqrt 2 + c_n\sqrt 2 = (b_n + c_n) \sqrt 2$

And $(1 + \sqrt 2)^{n+1} + (1 - \sqrt 2)^{n+1} = $

$(1 + \sqrt 2)^n(1 + \sqrt 2) + (1 - \sqrt 2)^n(1 - \sqrt 2) =$

$(1 + \sqrt 2)^n + \sqrt 2(1+ \sqrt 2)^n + (1-\sqrt 2)^n - (1-\sqrt 2)^n\sqrt 2 =$

$(1 + \sqrt 2)^n + (1-\sqrt 2)^n + \sqrt 2(1+ \sqrt 2)^n - (1-\sqrt 2)^n\sqrt 2 =$

$c_n  - b_n\sqrt 2\sqrt 2 = c_n - 2b_n$.

Although the best way to do this is with that binomial theorem.

$(1 \pm \sqrt 2)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n (\pm 1)^n {n\choose k}\sqrt 2^k$.

If $k$ is even then $(-1)^k =1$ so for

$(1+\sqrt2)^n - (1-\sqrt 2)^n =\sum_{k=0}^n (1-(-1)^k) {n\choose k}\sqrt 2^k$

the even terms will vanish.

If $k$ is odd then $(1-(-1)^k) = 2$ and $\sqrt 2^k = 2^{\frac {k-1}2}\sqrt 2$.

So

$(1+\sqrt2)^n - (1-\sqrt 2)^n =\sum_{k=0}^n (1-(-1)^k) {n\choose k}\sqrt 2^k=$

$\sum_{k=0; k \text{ odd}}^n 2{n\choose k}2^{\frac {k-1}2}\sqrt 2=$

$\sqrt 2(\sum_{k=0; k \text{ odd}}^n 2{n\choose k}2^{\frac {k-1}2}) =$

$\sqrt 2 b_n$ if we set $b_n$ equal to $\sum_{k=0; k \text{ odd}}^n 2{n\choose k}2^{\frac {k-1}2}$ which is an integer.