# Help with easy proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My name is Dennis and I need help solving.

> Show that if $n\in\mathbb Z$ is odd, then $n$ is of the form $4q+1$ or $4q+3$ for some $q\in\mathbb Z$.

Now I know this is true so can't use a proof by contradiction.

However I believe I can proof this by proving that $4q+1$ or $4q+3$ is not even thus it must be odd.

Below is my work it will not be the greatest for I have been away from math for some years.

Suppose to the contrary that $n$ is even.
consider $n$ to be even and we know an even integer is of the form $n=2k$
let $k=2q$ and we assume that $n=2(2q)+1$ or if rewritten $n=2k+1$
therefore $n=2k+1\neq n4q+1$ and $4q+1$ and $4q+3$ are odd.

Comment: You are proving that if $n$ is of that form then $n$ is odd. You're supposed to be proving that if $n$ is odd then it is of that form.

Comment: so I need to prove that all odd numbers of Z are in this form.
How would I do that, I would think that I would prove all even numbers or not of this form.

Comment: "Now I know this is true so can't use a proof by contradiction." A proof by contradiction doesn't usually prove false statements :).

Comment: O I seem to have misunderstood stood the use of that way of doing a proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n$ be an arbitrary odd number; we want to show that $n$ has the form $4q+1$ or $4q+3$.

But what does an "odd number" mean? It means something of the form $2m+1$ (for a whole number $m$), so the assumption is really $$n=2m+1$$

Now, $m$ itself is either even or odd. If we can show that no matter whether $m$ even or od then $n$ has one of the required forms, we will be through. If $m$ is even then $m=2k$ for some $k$, so
$$n=2m+1=2(2k)+1=4k+1$$
Then $k$ works as the $q$ we were looking for, which completes this case of the proof.

On the other hand, if $m$ is odd, that means $m=2k+1$ for some $k$, and then
$$n=2m+1=2(2k+1)+1=4k+2+1=4k+3$$
Then again $k$ works as $q$, and the proof is finished.

**Alternative proof.** We can also show the required implication in "contrapositive" form:

> If $n$ does *not* have one of the forms $4q+1$ or $4q+3$, then $n$ is *even*.

We can always divide $n$ by 4 and get an integral quotient and remainder instead of continuing into decimans. This allows us to express *any* $n$ as
$$n=4q+r$$
where $r$ is either zero or a positive number less than $4$, that is, one of the numbers 0, 1, 2, or 3. By assumption $r=1$ and $r=3$ cannot be the case, so we have either $n=4q+0$ or $n=4q+2$. In either case $n$ is the sum of two even numbers ($4q$ is always even, and 0 and 2 are also even), and that means that $n$ is even too.

Comment: And, if needed, we can prove that the sum of two even numbers is even...(+1)$$$$ ;)

Answer (score 2):

We can either $n$ divide by $4$.

That is, write $n=4q+r$, where $r,q\in\mathbb N$ and $r<4$. We have four options:

- $r=0$, then $n$ is divisible by $4$, which makes it even.
- $r=1$, then $n$ is indeed of the form $4q+1$.
- $r=2$, then $n=4q+2$ which is the sum of two even numbers ($4q$ is even).
- $r=3$, then $n=4q+3$.

Since $n$ is *odd* we have that either $r=1$ or $r=3$, and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

If the remainder x when dividing by 4 was 4 or greater, 4 could be subtracted from x and 1 added to q until a remainder <4 is obtained. The possibilites for n are then 4q, 4q+1,4q+2 and 4q+3. 4q=2(2q) and 4q+2=2(2q+1), therefore n is even if n is not of the form 4q+1 or 4q+3.

Comment: So I should be using the division algorithm? to prove that for when n is odd the "remainder is odd as well?"

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use proof by contradiction. Namely, suppose for contradiction that $\rm\:n\:$ is odd and not of the form $\rm\:4\:k+1\:$ or $\rm\:4\:k+3\:.\:$ By the Division algorithm we may write $\rm\: n = 4\ q + r\ $ for $\rm\ 0 \le r \le 3\:.\:$ By hypothesis $\rm\: r \ne 1,3\:$ so $\rm\:r = 0\ or\ 2\:$ is even, so  $\rm\:n = 4\ q + r\:$ is even, contra hypothesis. $\ $ **QED**

More generally one can show that if $\rm\:m\:$ is even then $\rm\:m\ q+r\:$ is odd $\:$ iff $\rm\ r\:$ is odd, simply because even + r = odd iff r is odd. This implies that the sense of "parity" descends from integers to integers modulo $\rm\:m\:,\:$ i.e. they have well-defined parity since it depends only on the remainder $\rm\:r\:,\:$ not on the quotient $\rm\:q\:.\:$ Further, all the usual rules of parity arithmetic also descend to the ring of integers modulo $\rm\:m\:,\:$  for example: $\:$ odd + even = odd, $\:$ odd^2 = odd,$\:$  etc - just as for integers. In fact there are many rings which similarly have a sense of parity, e.g. the Gaussian integers $\:\mathbb Z[i]\:$ where $\: a +  b\ i\ $ is even iff both $\:a\:$ and $\:b\:$ have the same parity. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26837/do-odd-imaginary-numbers-exist/26843#26843) for further discussion. Many of these matters will become clearer if one studies abstract algebra, esp. the concept of *quotient rings*, which generalizes the "modular" construction of the ring of integers modulo $\rm\:m\:.$

Comment: This is a very good post and helps me see I am clearly missing some basic understanding. My ability to write proofs is very weak. I believe I better start working on this if I aim to do well in this abstract algebra class.