# Is $\pi$ even or odd?

Tags: number-theory, pi, parity

This question is a question in my textbook, and I cannot stop thinking about it. The question: Is $\pi$ even or odd? I don't know if even or odd is defined for decimals or for irrational numbers, or if it is, how to find whether $\pi$ is even or odd. Can somebody help?

Comment: Neither of them...

Comment: *Which* textbook?

Comment: Even if the last digit decides whether a non-integer is even or odd, we cannot answer the question because $\pi$ has no last digit.

Answer (score 2):

Even numbers and odd numbers are defined only for integers, as an integer is even when it is of form $2k$, where $k$ is an integer, an integer is odd when it is of form $2p+1$, where $p$ is an integer. But $\pi$ is irrational(in fact transcedental). So there is no way of this.

Comment: Not true. In fact parity is well defined for may rings of (irrational) algebraic integers, including Gaussian integers $\,\Bbb Z[i],\,$ e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26843/242)

Comment: I am pretty sure the OP meant only for the ring $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: OP said nothing of the sort, and many of the rings I mention (enjoying parity) are subrings of $\Bbb R.\ $

Comment: @user665856 So should we consider such a statement  "$\pi$ is even" a false statement or meaningless?