# If $a=4$ and $b=3+3i$, are there any u,v such that $ua+vb=−1+5i$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

We have $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$

$a=4$

$b=3+3i$

Then, are there any $u, v \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $ua+vb=−1+5i$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: In general, you can use Euclid's algorithm. If there is a solution, then $\frac{(-1+5i)-vb}{a}\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Now, compute the remainders $r_1,r_2$ of the division of $-1+5i$ and $b$ by $a$. Then there is $u_1\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $au_1=r_1-vr_2$. Now, repeat but this time with $r_2$: We must have $\frac{r_1-au_1}{r_2}\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Compute the remainders $r_3,r_4$ of $r_1$ and $a$ divided by $r_2$. Then there is $v_1\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $r_2v_1=r_3-r_4u_1$. Eventually you get to either a solution or a constant quotient that is not in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: @DonThousand:  OP asked for $u,v\in\mathbb{ \color{red}Z[i]}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I clearly don't know how to read, lmao.

Comment: Split into real part and imaginary part, solve simultaneous equations.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$a=(1+i)(2-2i)$

$b=(1+i)3$

Comment: And $-1+5i=(1+i)(2+3i)$

Comment: @Don There is no need to factor - a parity test suffices - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: with the [same proof as in $\Bbb Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) (or any PID), $\,\exists\, x,y\!:\ ax+by = c\iff \gcd(a,b)\mid c.\ $ Recall that $\,\Bbb Z[i]\,$ has a constructive  (norm) Euclidean algorithm so we can always quickly compute this gcd, which determines solvabilty (and also the general solution - by scaling - follow the link).

---

**Or**:  $\,(4,3(1\!+\!i)) = (4,i\!+\!1) = 1\!+\!i,\ $ by $\ 1\!+\!i\mid j\!+\!ki\iff 2\mid j\!-\!k\ $ (so $\ 1\!+\!i\mid -1\!+\!5i),\,$ thus

$$\begin{align} &4x + (3\!+\!3i) y \,=\, j\! +\! ki\ \ {\rm  is\ solvable}\\[.2em]
 \iff\ &1\!+\!i\mid j\!+\!ki\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ \ 1\!+\!i = \gcd(4,\,3\!+\!3i)\\[.2em]
\iff\  &\ \ \ \ \ 2\mid j\!-\!k\\[.2em]
\iff\ &\ \ \ \ \ \ j,\,k\ \,\text{have equal parity}\end{align}\qquad$$

This is equivalent to saying that $\,j\!+\!ki\,$ is "even" in $\,\Bbb Z[i],\,$ as is explained in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26843/242) on notions of parity for algebraic numbers.