# If $n^2$ is even then $n$ is even: examples

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that if $n^2$ is even then $n$ is even, but take $n^2 = 6$, which is even. However, $n = \sqrt 6$ is not even? So what is going on?

Is it because $P \implies Q$ is false when $P$ is true and $Q$ is false?

Comment: "even" and "odd" are properties of integers, not arbitrary real numbers. The statement you wuote is about **integers**. That is the particular inferno at issue here.

Comment: We [can in fact extend the notion of parity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26843/242) to $\Bbb Z[\sqrt 6],\,$ where $\sqrt 6$ is even.

Comment: In other words: first choose an integer *n* (this is the part you're missing). Now look at whether $n^2$ is even. If it is, then $n$ is even.

Comment: I agree Arturo.

Answer (score 2):

The theorem is that if $n$ is an INTEGER such that $n^2$ is even, then $n$ itself is even. Of course, if you just give me any even number, it's square root doesn't have to be even, because it's square root doesn't have to be an integer in the first place, as your example shows. However, if the square root is an integer, then it will have to be even.

Btw, you can replace every instance of the word even with the word odd in what I just said, and it will still be true verbatim.