# If $a^2$ divides $b^2$, then $a$ divides $b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers. Prove that: If $a^2$ divides $b^2$, then $a$ divides $b$.

Context: the lecturer wrote this up in my notes without proving it, but I can't seem to figure out why it's true. Would appreciate a solution.

Comment: Do you have the fundamental theorem of arithmetic at your disposal?

Comment: Yep! We covered that a couple weeks ago.

Comment: Hint: if $a^2|b^2$ then $b^2=?$ and $?$ is a perfect square so ...

Comment: Hint: If $b^2 = k a^2$ then using FTA what can you say about $k$? Perfect square. Why? Something about the even powers of primes.

Comment: Jennifer: 
My version of the FTA just says that every positive integer greater than 1 is a unique product of prime numbers (upto reorderings). Why does that imply that k is a perfect square?

Mark: I can't see where to go next..

Comment: If $a =$ product of primes with some powers, then $a^2 = $ product of the same primes with *twice* the same powers; that is, even powers. Same goes for $b^2.$ Can you see why $k$ has to have primes factorization with *even* powers as well?

Comment: By the way, on stackexchange network, users only get notified *if* you type `@` before their usernames. E.g. @Anthony @JenniferDylan .

Comment: Another perspective: this follows from the well known fact that if $n$ is a positive integer then $\sqrt{n}$ is either an integer or irrational.

Comment: @SeanEberhard I'd appreciate it if you could elaborate. We actually covered this result in the same lecture.

Comment: @JenniferDylan Thanks! I see what you mean about k now.

Comment: There are *many* prior answers on the irrationality of square roots, e.g. see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/4467/242) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/16544/242) and [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/22444/242)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of arithemtic, you can write $a$ and $b$ as a product of primes, say
$$
a=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_r^{\alpha_r},\qquad b=p_1^{\beta_1}\cdots p_r^{\beta_r}
$$
where $\alpha_i,\beta_i\geq 0$. Allow the exponents to possibly be $0$ if such a prime $p_i$ occurs in the factorization of one integer but not the other.

So $a^2=p_1^{2\alpha_1}\cdots p_r^{2\alpha_r}$ and $b^2=p_1^{2\beta_1}\cdots p_r^{2\beta_r}$. Since $a^2\mid b^2$, by unique factorization, necessarily $2\alpha_i\leq 2\beta_i$ for each $i$. That implies $\alpha_i\leq\beta_i$ for all $i$, and so $a\mid b$.

Comment: Thanks very much! Took me a while just to work through and understand that proof (a little embarrassing).

Comment: @Anthony Glad to help, and welcome to math.se. By the way, if an answer suits you, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left. This essentially marks the question as "done," but feel free to wait a while as other, and better, answers may come along later.

Comment: This method actually proves that $a^n \mid b^n \implies a \mid b$ for any $n \geq 1$ as I showed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25716/show-that-an-bn-implies-a-b/25719#25719).

Comment: I don't understand why 2αi≤2βi, and that too "necessarily".

Comment: Is it necessary that the prime factorisation of $a$ and $b$...will have equal number of primes and the same primes? $b$ can have more primes than $a$...

Comment: No, that's why I allowed the exponents to be $0$ if one prime occurs in $a$ and not $b$, or vice versa. $\{p_1,\dots,p_r\}$ is just the union of primes in the factorizations of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 34):

To say that $a^2$ divides $b^2$ is to say that $n=b^2/a^2 = (b/a)^2$ is an integer. Now integers only have square roots which are integers or irrational. Since $b/a$ is rational, it must be an integer, which is to say that $a$ divides $b$.

Comment: Hmm... if I wanted to prove that the square root of an integer was either an integer or irrational, I'd probably do it by proving the OP's statement, making this circular. Do you have a different proof in mind?

Comment: @Micah see [Bill's comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182988/if-a2-divides-b2-then-a-divides-b#comment421983_182988).

Comment: +1. Really very simple proof, that makes no appeal to the Funda-Theorem of Arithmetic.

Comment: @Iyengar, the standard proof that integers only have square roots that are integers or irrational, that proof uses the Fundamental Theorem.

Answer (score 19):

Call a positive integer $y$ **bad** if for some positive $x$, we have $x^2\mid y^2$ but $x \nmid y$.

If there are bad positive integers, there is a smallest bad one, say $b$. Since $b$ is bad, there is a positive integer $a$ such that $a^2 \mid b^2$ but $a \nmid b$.

It is clear that $a \ne 1$. So some prime $p$ divides $a^2$. But if a prime divides the product $cd$, it divides $c$ or $d$ or both. Thus $p\mid a$.

Since $a^2\mid b^2$, we have $p\mid b^2$, and therefore $p\mid b$.

Let $a=pa_1$ and $b=pb_1$. Since $a^2\mid b^2$, we have $(pa_1)^2=q(pb_1)^2$ for some integer $q$, and therefore $a_1^2\mid b_1^2$.

But $a_1\nmid b_1$, since if it does, one can easily  show that $a\mid b$.

So we have shown that $b_1$ is bad. It is clear that $b_1\lt b$, which contradicts the supposed minimality of $b$.

We conclude that there are no bad positive integers.

Comment: Remark that this is essentially the same proof as that in yunone's answer (by *unique factorization*), but rearranged into descent form.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Agreed. It uses the same key step as the standard proof of the Unique Factorization Theorem.

Answer (score 7):

The proofs given use the Unique Factorization Theorem, or the existence of GCDs, or some equivalent, but the result is true even in places where there aren't any GCDs, so there must be a proof that doesn't rely on these properties. Here's one that works in the ring $O_K$ of integers in a number field $K$, whether there are GCDs or not.

If $a,b$ are in $O_K$ and $a^2$ divides $b^2$, then $b^2=a^2c$ for some $c$ in $O_K$. So $\sqrt c=b/a$ is in $K$. But $\sqrt c$ is a zero of $x^2-c$, a monic polynomial with algebraic integer coefficients, so $\sqrt c$ is an algebraic integer, so $\sqrt c$ is in $O_K$, so $a$ divides $b$.

Comment: So, you only need to assume the ring to be integrally closed.

Comment: @lhf, yes, that sounds about right.

Comment: "... but the result is true even in places where there aren't any GCDs." This is incorrect. Let $K$ be a field, and let $R=K[x^2,x^3]=\{a_0 + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \cdots + a_n x^n \,\vert\,a_i \in K\}$ be the subring of $K[x]$ that has no linear terms. Then $(x^2)^2 \vert (x^3)^2$, but $x^2\nmid x^3$.

Comment: @Jack, sorry, I thought it would be clear that I was saying that the result is true even in *some* places where there aren't any GCDs. Thanks for providing an example of a ring where the result fails.

Answer (score 7):

An argument that uses only the definition of divisibility and the well-ordering principle.

Let $k$ be the smallest positive integer for which $a \mid bk$.  Suppose $l$ is the integer for which $bk = al$ and $m$ is the integer for which $b^2 = a^2 m$.  Then $a b l = b^2 k = a^2 k m$, so that $b l = a k m$.

Use the division algorithm ([an easy consequence of well-ordering](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/%7Elee/courses/Division.pdf)) and write $l = kq + r$ with $0 \leq r < k$.  Then $br = a k m - b k q = a (k m - l q)$. Thus, $a \mid br$.  From our assumption that $k$ is the smallest positive integer for which $a \mid bk$, we find that $r=0$.

Thus, $l = kq$, so $bk = al = akq$, so $b = aq$ and $a$ divides $b$.

(This implies also that if $a^{2^k} \mid b^{2^k}$, then $a \mid b$. I don't see immediately an extension that works to prove that if $a^n \mid b^n$, then $a \mid b$, but am happy to edit if someone else does.)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative proof only relying on a more general definition of greatest common divisors (in commutative [monoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) or [commutative rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_ring)). In particular, we say that $gcd(a,b)=d$ if:

- $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$ (ie $d\vert a$ and $d \vert b$), and
- Given any other common divisor $d'$ of $a$ and $b$, we have $d'\vert d$

Throughout this proof, we'll assume that we're in a commutative monoid for which every pair of elements has a greatest common divisor (or, if you'd prefer, you can imagine just sticking to $\mathbb{N}$ under multiplication).

So, suppose that $a^2 \vert b^2$, and let $gcd(a,b)=d$. Then, we have $d\alpha =a$ and $d\beta = b$ for some $\alpha,\beta$. It then follows that $gcd(\alpha,\beta)=1$ (if you're unsure as to why, it would be worth the time to write down a proof using the definition of GCD given above).

Now, since $a^2 \vert b^2$, there exists $k$ such that $a^2 k = b^2$, and hence $\alpha^2 k = \beta^2$. Therefore we have $\alpha \vert \beta^2$ implying that $\alpha \vert \beta$ (if you're not sure as to why, again, it would be worth writing down a proof).  However, $gcd(\alpha,\beta)=1$ and $\alpha \vert \beta$ implies that $\alpha=1$ (or, more generally, $\alpha$ is an invertible element in our monoid), hence $gcd(a,b)=a$ and $a \vert b$.

In fact, this same line of argument shows that if $a^m \vert b^m$ for some $m\geq 2$, then $a \vert b$.

Answer (score 1):

$a^2 \mid b^2 \Rightarrow \frac{a}{d}\cdot\frac{a}{d} \mid \frac{b}{d}\cdot\frac{b}{d}$ with $d = gcd(a,b)$. From $gcd(\frac{a}{d},\frac{b}{d})=1$ follows $\frac{a}{d}=1$ or $a=d \mid b$.

This can easily be extended to $a^m \mid b^n$ where $2 \le n \le m$.

Answer (score 0):

Let, *a* = $p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2} ... p_k^{\alpha_k}$ and *b* = $p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2} ... p_k^{\beta_k}$

Then, $a^2$ = $p_1^{2\alpha_1}p_2^{2\alpha_2}... p_k^{2\alpha_k} $ and $b^2$ = $p_1^{2\beta_1}p_2^{2\beta_2} ... p_k^{2\beta_k}$

Since $a^2|b^2$:
$b^2/a^2$ = $p_1^{2(\beta_1 - \alpha_1)}p_2^{2(\beta_2 - \alpha_2)}... p_k^{2(\beta_k - \alpha_k)} $

Taking the square root of both sides:
$b/a$ = $p_1^{\beta_1 - \alpha_1}p_2^{\beta_2 - \alpha_2}... p_k^{\beta_k - \alpha_k} $
This implies *a|b* since $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are both integers

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What's the point of prviding this answer more than 5 years after the question was asked and when the accepted answer is exactly the same as yours?