# UFDs are integrally closed; so too are GCD & Dedekind domains.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

Let $A$ be a UFD, $K$ its field of fractions, and $f$ an element of $A[T]$ a monic polynomial.

I'm trying to prove that if $f$ has a root $\alpha \in K$, then in fact $\alpha \in A$.

I'm trying to exploit the fact of something about irreducibility, will it help? I havent done anything with splitting fields, but this is something i can look for.

Comment: If you are familiar with The Rational Root Theorem, I should think you could recast it in your more general setting.

Comment: You can find a proof of your theorem, [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/UFD_is_Integrally_Closed)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The proof follows exactly like the proof of the Rational Root Theorem.

Let $\alpha\in K$ be a root. We can express $\alpha$ as $\frac{a}{b}$ with $a,b\in A$, and using unique factorization we may assume that no irreducible of $A$ divides both $a$ and $b$.

If $f(x) = x^n + c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+c_0$, then plugging in $\alpha$ and multiplying through by $b^n$ we obtain
$$a^n + c_{n-1}ba^{n-1}+\cdots + c_0b^n = 0.$$
Now, $c_{n-1}ba^{n-1}+\cdots+c_0b^n$ is divisible by $b$, hence $a^n$ is divisible by $b$. Since no irreducible of $A$ divides both $a$ and $b$, it follows that $b$ must be a unit by unique factorization. Hence $\alpha\in A$.

Comment: Why does $b$ a unit imply that $a/b \in A$?

Comment: @AlJebr Because if $b$ is a unit then $a/b = ab^{-1}$ and both $a$ and $b^{-1}$ are in $A$. Why isn’t that obvious?

Comment: Ahh right. I also did right now $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{a}{b}\frac{b^{-1}}{b^{-1}}=ab^{-1} \in R$.

Answer (score 3):

**Overkill:** It suffices to show that $A$ is integrally closed, which we prove using [Serre's criterion](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/031S). For this, we recall some of the definitions, including the [definitions](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/033P) of the properties $R_n$ and $S_n$ that appear in Serre's criterion. We will assume $A$ is locally [Noetherian](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00FM) (can one assume less for this approach to work?)

**Background**

*Definition*. A ring $A$ is said to satisfy the criterion $R_n$ if for every prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $A$ such that $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak p)\le n$, the localization $A_{\mathfrak p}$ is a [regular local ring](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00KU), which means that the maximal ideal can be generated by $\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak p)$ elements.

*Definition*. A Noetherian ring $A$ is said to satisfy the criterion $S_n$ if for every prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $A$, we have the inequality $$\operatorname{depth}(A_{\mathfrak p}) \ge \min\{n,\operatorname{ht}(\mathfrak p)\}$$
This relies on the notion of [depth](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00LE), which is the length of a maximal regular sequence in the maximal ideal.

*Exercise*. Give a definition of the $S_n$ condition for modules. (Note: there are actually two distinct definitions in the literature, which only agree when the annihilator of the module is a nilpotent ideal.)

*Exercise*. Show that a Noetherian ring $A$ is reduced if and only if $A$ satisfies $R_0$ and $S_1$.

With these definitions out of the way, we now state the criterion of which we will benefit.

*Theorem*. (Serre's Criterion). A Noetherian integral domain $A$ is integrally closed if and only if $A$ has the properties $R_1$ and $S_2$.

---

**Proof that UFDs are Integrally Closed**

Firstly, localizations of UFDs are UFDs while intersections of integrally closed domains in the field of fractions of $A$ are integrally closed. Recalling that $A=\bigcap_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Spec}A} A_{\mathfrak p}$, we may assume $A$ is local. Now, $A$ is $R_1$ because prime ideals $\mathfrak p$ of height $1$ are [principal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2548309/every-prime-ideal-of-height-1-in-a-ufd-is-principal) and thus $A_{\mathfrak p}$ is a DVR. Also, $A$ is $S_1$ because $A$ is an integral domain and thus reduced, while for any irreducible $f\in A$ we have $A/fA$ is an integral domain, so $A/fA$ is $S_1$. This implies
\begin{equation*}
    \operatorname{depth} A \ge \min\{2,\dim A\}
\end{equation*}
The argument works for any local UFD, in particular the localizations of $A$. So, $A$ is $S_2$. By Serre's criterion, $A$ is integrally closed.

Comment: You haven't defined $R_1, S_1, S_2$ (nor does your link).

Comment: This answer was intended to be on the ridiculous side. I can edit in some of the relevant definitions, though.

Answer (score 2):

The [well-known simple proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658006/why-rational-root-theorem-only-works-with-integers/658058?s=1%7C1.6955#658058) of RRT = **Rational Root Test** [remains valid](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4343557/242) in a UFD or GCD domain. The sought result is simply the special case when $\:\!\rm f(x)\:\!$ is monic (lead coef $=1$).

---

**Generalization:** $ $  we prove RRT in a form that works for both $\rm\color{#0a0}{gcds}$ and *cancellable* $\rm\color{#c00}{ideals}$ by using only universal laws common to both (commutative, associative, distributive etc). Below we give such a universal proof for degree $3\,$ (to avoid notational obfuscation). It should be clear how this generalizes to any degree.

If $\rm\:D\:$ is a $\rm\color{#0a0}{gcd}$ domain and monic $\rm\:f(x)\in D[x]\:$ has root $\rm\:a/b,\ a,b\in D\,$ then

$\rm\qquad f(x)\, =\, c_0 + c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + x^3,\:$ and $\rm\:b^3\:\! f(a/b) = 0\:$ yields

$\rm\qquad c_0 b^3 + c_1 a b^2 + c_2 a^2 b\, =\, -a^3\ $

$\rm\qquad\qquad\ \ \,\Rightarrow\ (b^3, a b^2,\, a^2 b)\mid \color{#c00}{a^3},\ $ by the gcd divides LHS of above so also  RHS

$\rm\qquad\ (b,a)^3 = \, (b^3,\, a b^2,\, a^2 b,\  \color{#c00}{a^3}),\  $ so, by the prior divisibility

$\rm\qquad\qquad\quad\:\! =\, (b^3,\, a b^2,\, a^2 b) $

$\rm\qquad\qquad\quad =\, b\, (b,a)^2,\ $ so cancelling $\rm\,(b,a)^2$ yields

$\rm\qquad\ \, (b,a) =\, b\:\Rightarrow\: b\:|\:a,\ $ i.e. $\rm\: a/b \in D.\ \ $ **QED**

The degree $\rm\:n> 1\:$ case has the same form: we cancel $\rm\:(b,a)^{n-1}$ from $\rm\,(b,a)^n = b\,(b,a)^{n-1}.$

The $\rm\color{#c00}{ideal}$ analog is the same, except replace "divides" by "contains", and assume that $\rm\,(a,b)\ne 0\,$ is invertible (so cancellable), e.g. in any Dedekind domain. Thus the above yields a uniform proof that PIDs, UFDs, GCD and Dedekind domains satisfy said monic case of the Rational Root Test, i.e. that they are **integrally closed.**

The proof is more concise using *fractional* gcds and ideals. Now, with $\rm\:r = a/b,\:$ we simply cancel $\rm\:(r,1)\:$ from $\rm\:(r,1)^n = (r,1)^{n-1}$ so $\rm\:(r,1) = (1),\:$ i.e. $\rm\:r \in D.\:$ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39769/242) for further details.