# Prime ideal in a polynomial ring over an integrally closed domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, integral-domain

> Let $R$ be an integrally closed domain. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R[x]$ with the property that $P\cap R=\left\{ 0\right\} $ and $P$ contains a monic polynomial. Prove that $P$ is principal.

Help me a hint to prove.

Thank for any insight.

Comment: To prove $P$ is principal, you need to show some element of $P$ divides every other element of $P$.  What are the candidates for this job?

Comment: Can consider the minimal polynomial of $P$?

Comment: Hint: $P$ corresponds to a prime ideal in $Q(R)[x]$.

Comment: What is $Q(R)[x]$?

Comment: Is it the quotiens field of $R[x]$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342891

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $P$ is a prime ideal of $R[x]$ that contains a monic polynomial and whose intersection with the base ring, integrally closed domain $R$, is trivial, $P \cap R = \{0\}$.

We are asked to prove that $P$ is principal.  In other words we need to show $P$ contains an element that divides all the polynomials in $P$.  What are the candidates?

We know that $P$ contains a monic polynomial, so let's start there.  While $P$ will certainly contain more than one monic polynomial, we know that $P$ is a prime ideal.  This suggests that we want to get at irreducibility of the monic polynomial.

One way to do this is by picking a monic polynomial of *minimal degree* in $P$.  Note that since $P$ has trivial intersection with $R$, the degree of any polynomial in $P$ must be at least 1.

Now use the primality of $P$ to show that any monic polynomial $f$ of minimal degree in $P$ must be irreducible.  Primality of $P$ means that if $f = gh$, either $g \in P$ or $h \in P$.  If $f = gh$ is monic, then both $g,h$ are monic (up to multiplication by units).  Thus $P$ would contain a monic polynomial of degree less than the degree of $f$; contradiction.

Finally, use some ideas from the division algorithm to show such $f$ divides every element of $P$.

---

At this point the fact $R$ is integrally closed comes into play.  The Question connects this to $R[x]$ also being integrally closed.  Though we are not asked to prove that, it bears noting it is an easy consequence of this:

**Lemma** Let domain $R$ be integrally closed in its field of quotients $k$.  If $g,h \in k[x]$ are monic polynomials such that $gh \in R[x]$, then $g,h \in R[x]$.

If $R$ were a UFD, this could be considered a corollary of [Gauss's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_(polynomial)) on polynomial irreducibility (see [Prop. 1 here](http://people.math.binghamton.edu/mazur/teach/gausslemma.pdf)), but using [the weaker assumption](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150554/ufds-are-integrally-closed) of $R$ being integrally closed, here supplemented by assuming monicity of $gh$ over mere primitivity.  A proof bears a few words of elaboration.

**Proof of Lemma:** In the algebraic closure $\overline{k}$ of $k$, we can fully factor $g = \Pi (x-a_i), h = \Pi (x-b_j)$, so that the coefficients of $g$ are (elementary symmetric) polynomial expressions in roots $a_i$, and similarly the coefficients of $h$ in roots $b_j$.  Since the roots $a_i,b_j$ are also roots of monic polynomial $gh \in R[x]$, they are integral over $R$.  Dedekind (1877) showed the integral elements over a domain form a ring (this is covered in [J. Milne's Algebraic Number Theory](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf), Chapt. 2), so the coefficients of $g$ (resp. of $h$) are also integral over $R$.  But these coefficients are in $k$, and $R$ is integrally closed in $k$, so the polynomials $g,h$ are in $R[x]$.  QED

Since prime ideal $P \subseteq R[x]$ contains no nonzero constant, by a standard argument $kP$ is a proper ideal of $k[x]$ and $kP \cap R[x] = P$. As $k[x]$ is a Euclidean domain (division algorithm, degree argument), there $kP$ is a principal ideal, say generated by monic polynomial $g$.  Because $f \in P \subseteq kP$, $f = gh$ for some monic $h \in k[x]$.  Then, according to the Lemma, $g \in kP \cap R[x] = P$ and by irreducibility of $f$, $f = g$.

Now apply the observation user89712 makes in a comment under his answer: Since $f$ is monic, any element of $P$ can be expressed as $qf + r \in R[x]$ "by division algorithm" where $\deg(r) \lt \deg(f)$. However the same is true in Euclidean domain $k[x]$ where we see by uniqueness that $r=0$ (since $f=g$ generates $kP$).  Thus $f$ divides every element of $P$ over $R[x]$, as we wished to show.

Comment: I need more details on the proof that any polynomial $f$ of minimal degree in $P$ must be irreducible. Can you explain more precisely to me?

Comment: Is that enough detail?

Comment: Yes it's enough.

Comment: For the proof that such $f$ divides every element of $P$, I don't understand why we can prove. The last time, can you explain more precisely to me?

Comment: I think you can use the fact that $R[x]$ is an integrally closed domain.

Comment: @hardmath: Help me.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/653763/242) and [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/751931/242)

Comment: This may be weird since I'm asking like 3 years later, but do you know a proof of the lemma that you wrote, without using notions as "algebraic closure" or the fact that sums and products of integral elements are integral too?

Comment: @Xam:  I thought about this a bit.  I think it might be possible to avoid the algebraic closure of the field, as this seems to be a convenience to the argument rather than an essential idea.  However "the fact that sums and products of integral elements are integral too" strikes me as a basic idea here.  In addition to the links Bill Dubuque gives above, see the way [this class Exercise](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~nava/Exercise_2.pdf) was handled. If interested in pursuing it, feel free to ask a new Question and link here for context.

Comment: Giving links instead of statements and proofs is a bad idea since some are dead now.

Comment: @user26857: Thanks for calling to my attention the broken links.  I've made some changes to ones that were either 404 or otherwise impaired.  I believe that the statement and proof of the Lemma, and its application to the secondary issue of $R[x]$ being integrally closed, were already sufficiently detailed.  But if you feel otherwise please comment or invite me to chat.

Answer (score 8):

Take $S=R-\{0\}$ and consider $S^{-1}(R[x])=(S^{-1}R)[x]$. (In the following denote by $K$ the field of fractions of $R$, that is $K=S^{-1}R$.) Then $S^{-1}P$ is prime in $K[x]$, so there exists $p\in K[x]$ monic such that $S^{-1}P=pK[x]$. Since $P$ contains a monic polynomial $f$ we get $f=pg$, $g\in K[x]$. Now use Gauss' lemma to get $p\in R[x]$ and prove that $P=pR[x]$.

Comment: Why $S^{-1}R
 $ is prime in $K[x]$?

Comment: Since $P$ is prime in $R[x]$, $S^{-1}P$ is prime in $K[x]=S^{-1}R[x]$

Comment: @user: I need more details on the proof that $P=pR[x]$. Can you give me more details on it?

Comment: An element of $P$ is a multiple of $p$ in $K[x]$ and in the same time it's of the form $pq+r$ in $R[x]$ by division algorithm (this works since $p$ is monic). Now use the uniqueness of $q$ and $r$ in $K[x]$ and find $r=0$.