# Monic polynomial reducible over rationals (Gauss's Lemma)

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $P(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, $Q(x),R(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, and all three polynomials are monic. Suppose $P(x)=Q(x)R(x)$. Is it true that $Q(x),R(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

[Gauss's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29) says that since $P(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, it must be reducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. But still it doesn't say that $Q,R\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the original form of Gauss's Lemma. A proof follows easily from said modern form GL.

Write $\,Q = \dfrac{f}c,\ R = \dfrac{g}d\, $ for primitive $\,f,g\in\Bbb Z[x],\,$ and $\,0 < c,d\in\Bbb Z,\,$ and suppose that $\, h = QR = fg/(cd) \in\Bbb Z[x],\,$ so $fg = cd\,h.\,$ [By GL:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2167166/242) $\,f,g\,$ primitive $\Rightarrow$ $fg$ primitive, so $\,c,d = 1,\,$ hence $\,Q =  f,\ R =  g,\,$ so both are $\in \Bbb Z[x].$

**Remark** $\ $ More generally the following is true. If $f,g\in\Bbb Q[x]$ and $\,fg\in\Bbb Z[x]\,$ then $\,f_i g_j\in \Bbb Z$ for all coefficients $f_i,g_j$ of $f,g.\,$ In particular, if $f$ is monic, taking $f_i = 1$ = leading coefficient, shows that every $\,g_j\in \Bbb Z,\,$ and, similarly every $f_i\in \Bbb Z,\,$ yielding the above special case.

This general form is true over any integrally-closed domain (it is equivalent to integral closure). This is sometimes called the Gauss-Kronecker Lemma, or Dedekind's Prague Theorem. Dedekind discovered a form applying to algebraic integers after studying a divisor-theoretic form that appeared in Kronecker's seminal work on divisor theory. For much further discussion, both historical and mathematical, see Harold Edwards, [Divisor Theory.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817634487)

Below is Gauss's original form of Gauss Lemma, from Art. $42$ of *Disq. Arith*. Notice that is of the form mentioned above, not the reformulated modern form using primitivity or content.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok, so $P=fg$, $f$ is primitive, and $Q$ is monic. Still it doesn't imply that $Q\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: @JJBeck  I added a proof using the modern form of Gauss's Lemma.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3636865/242)