# Is there a relationship between a polynomial and the $\gcd$ of its coefficients?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, gcd-and-lcm, integral-domain

Let $\mathfrak{D}$ be an integral domain with an identity, and let

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^na_nx^k$$

be some non-constant in the polynomial domain $\mathfrak{D}[x]$. Are there any non-trivial theorems on or relationships between $g=\gcd(a_0,a_1\dots a_n)$ and $f(x)$? Just a shower thought, couldn't conclude anything other than basic in the ten minutes I played with it.

Comment: The GCD is not always defined in an integral domain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the coefficient gcd is one definition of the [*content* $c(f)$ of a polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_part_and_content) over a [UFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) or [GCD domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain). An important result about such that plays a fundamental role in divisibility theory in polynomial rings is

[Gauss's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)) $\,\ c(fg)\, =\, c(f) c(g)\ $

One way to generalize this to arbitrary commutative rings is to define the content to be the ideal generated by the coefficients. Then we have

[Dedekind Mertens Lemma](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1998-126-05/S0002-9939-98-04165-3/S0002-9939-98-04165-3.pdf)  $\,\ c(f)^n c(fg)\, =\, c(f)^{n+1} c(g)\ $ for $\, n = \deg(g)\ \ ({\rm or\ \#terms}-1)$

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/653763/242)  for closely related versions (Dedekind's Prague theorem a.k.a. Gauss-Kronecker Lemma).

A comprehensive survey of this and related topics is D.D. Anderson: [GCD domains, Gauss' lemma, and contents of polynomials](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268316472_GCD_Domains_Gauss'_Lemma_and_Contents_of_Polynomials), 2000.

Kronecker used polynomial contents as a foundation (alternative to Dedekind's ideal theory) for the study of factorization in algebraic number rings - what is known as *divisor theory* nowadays. For a modern introduction see the following (and search on "Kronecker function rings")

Friedemann Lucius. [Rings with a theory of greatest common divisors.](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002239620)
manuscripta math. 95, 117-36 (1998).

Olaf Neumann. [Was sollen und was sind Divisoren?](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs591-002-8140-8#)
(What are divisors and what are they good for?)  Math. Semesterber, 48, 2, 139-192 (2001).