# Non-monic minimal polynomial implies non-integral element?

Tags: commutative-algebra

In a ring extension $R\subseteq S$, in order to check whether an element of $S$ is integral over $R$, I wonder why it is enough to check the minimal polynomial? In a concrete example, I found that the minimal polynomial was not monic (which we require for the element to be integral), how can I conclude from here that there is **no** monic polynomial with coefficients in $R$ annihilating the considered element of $S$? Couldn’t there be such a polynomial that simply has higher degree than the minimal one? Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is true iff $R$ is integrally closed, as follows by various forms of Gauss's Lemma, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/653763/242).

Comment: In the same vein as Bill's comment.... consider $D \subseteq K$ where $D$ is a domain and $K$ its field of fractions. Any element of $a/b \in K$ is a root of the linear polynomial $bx -a$.  Meanwhile, an element of $K \setminus D$ is integral over $D$ iff it is the root of a monic non-linear polynomial.