# Prime ideal $P$ of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $P \cap \mathbb{Z}=\{0\}$ is principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, ideals

The problem stated more precisely is this:

> Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $P \cap \mathbb{Z} =\{0\}$. Show that $P$ is a principal ideal.

I think there is a problem with my proof.

So I said that if $m(x)$ is a nonzero polynomial in $P$ of minimum degree then $P=(m(x))$. If $f(x) \in P$ is any polynomial then in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ there is $q(x),r(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $f(x)=q(x)m(x)+r(x) \implies r(x)=f(x)-q(x)m(x)$ with $r=0$ or the degree of r less than the degree of $m$. Letting $L$ be the LCM of the denominators of the coefficients we have $Lr(x)=Lf(x)-Lq(x)m(x) \implies Lr(x) \in P$.

> This is where the problem is. I want to claim that $Lr(x) \in P \implies L\in P$ or $r(x) \in P$. Obviously this then forces $r(x) \in P$ by the intersection assumption which then forces $r=0$. The problem is that $r(x)$ is not necessarily in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ so the prime condition on $P$ does not necessarily apply here. Is there a way to strengthen the condition on $m(x)$ to ensure that $r(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $r(x)\in\mathbb Q[x]$ and $Lr(x)\in P$ for some $L\in\mathbb Z$, $L\ne0$. Now multiply $Lr(x)$ by a non-zero integer $a$ such that $ar(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$, and find $Lar(X)\in P$. Then $ar(x)\in P$ and $\deg ar(x)=\deg r(x)<\deg m(x)$.

You have to be careful when start with $m\in P$, $\deg m\ge1$ of minimal degree to suppose that $m$ is primitive if want $P=(m(x))$, that is, the $\gcd$ of coefficients of $m$ is $1$. (You also need this assumption when $r=0$.) If this is not the case, then $m(x)=kn(x)\in P$ with $k\ge 2$ and $n(x)$ primitive, and then $n(x)\in P$ is a generator.

Answer (score 4):

Let  P be the prime ideal $P \subseteq \Bbb{Z}[x]$ and let it be not a principal ideal, so $P$ contains two non zero elements $f,g$ with no common factor in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$. We can prove this easy lemma-

**Lemma-** $f,g$ has no common factor in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$.

**Sketch-** If they have a common factor, say $h\in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ with degree $\ge1$, then writing $h=ah_0$ where $h_0$ is primitive polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$, we can easily show $h_0$ divides $f$ and $g$, which is a contradiction.

**Claim-** $P \cap \Bbb{Z}\neq 0$

**Proof-** Consider $I=\langle f,g \rangle \subseteq P$. As $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ is a PID, so it is a g.c.d domain, i.e. g.c.d exists, and by Lemma $f,g$ has no common factor in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$, therefore $(f,g)=1$ so, there exist $a,b\in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ (Because PIDs are Bezout domains) such that $$af+bg=1 \hspace{5cm}(*)$$

Now, multiplying $*$ by lcm of denominators $a$ and $b$, say $c$, we get $$P \ni caf+cbg=c\in \Bbb{Z}$$  So,  $P \cap \Bbb{Z}\neq 0$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I was writing this earlier, but then though $\Bbb{Z}$ is a gcd domain too, so bezout identity must hold there, why take the long cut. Thanks for pointing that out. I hope I am correct now

Comment: It appears to be okay now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct proof that uses localization and the following consequence of Gauss's Lemma: Let $R$ be a UFD with quotient field $Q$, and let $f, g \in R[x]$. If $f$ is primitive and $f$ divides $g$ in $Q[x]$, then $f$ divides $g$ in $R[x]$.

Here's the proof: Consider the multiplicative set $S = \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\} \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$. The localization $S^{-1} \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Q}[x]$, and because $S \cap P = \emptyset$, $P$ corresponds to an ideal $S^{-1}P \subset \mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Now $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a PID, so we can find a generator $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ for $S^{-1} P$. In fact, we can choose this generator to be in $P \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$, and we can choose it to be primitive.

To see that we can assume the generator is in $P$, note that any polynomial in $S^{-1} P$ can be written as $\frac{f}{s}$ for some $f \in P$ and $s \in S$, and the ideals $\frac{f}{s} \cdot \mathbb{Q}[x] = \frac{f}{1} \cdot \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Therefore, we can assume the generator is in $P \subset S^{-1} P$.

To see that we can assume the generator is primitive, recall that any polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ can be written as $f = \text{cont}(f) \cdot f_{\text{prim}}$, where $\text{cont}(f) \in S$ is the content of $f$, and $f_{\text{prim}} \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is primitive. Moreover since $P$ is prime, if $f = \text{cont}(f) \cdot f_{\text{prim}} \in P$ then either $\text{cont}(f) \in P$ or $f_{\text{prim}} \in P$. But $\text{cont}(f) \in S$ and $S \cap P = \emptyset$, so $f_{\text{prim}} \in P$. And as ideals, $f \cdot \mathbb{Q}[x] = f_{\text{prim}} \cdot \mathbb{Q}[x]$, so we can assume the generator of $S^{-1}P \subset \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a primitive polynomial $f \in P$.

Now consider any $g \in P$. Then $g \in S^{-1}P$, so $f$ divides $g$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, therefore $f$ also divides $g$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Thus $P = f \cdot \mathbb{Z}[x]$, and so $P$ is primitive. $\square$.