Every Prime Ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$Which is not Principal Contains a Prime?
I am working on an old qualifying exam problem, and I'm stuck. Here's the question:
Show every prime ideal $P$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ which is not principal contains a prime number.
I am aware that every prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is of one of the following types: $(0), (p), (p, f(x)), (f(x))$. This seems to solve the problem immediately though, so I assume I can't use it. The proofs of this result are longer than I'd expect the exam solution to be, though.
Is there a way to approach this without invoking/proving the classification of prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

If you can use the fact that ring of integer polynomials is noetherian, then for ideals do not contain any integers, you can use the euclidean division to find the greatest common divisor of the generating polynomials

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1342936/265452

Using the linked post:
Let $f,g\in P$. We may assume these polynomials are irreducible and not equal. Then $$(f,g)=(1)\subseteq\Bbb Q[x]$$ by Bezout's lemma. Now, there is an integer $n$ so that $(nf,ng)=(n)\subseteq\Bbb Z[x]$, which makes the coefficients integers.
But then $(n)\subseteq P$ and so $P$ contains a prime $p$ such that $p\mid n$.
