# How to prove that a polynomial with leading coefficient $1$ has no fractional solutions

Tags: polynomials, alternative-proof

I want to prove that the equation $$x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+\dots+a_0=0$$ has no solutions in the form of $p/q$ when $p$ and $q$ and coprime and $q>1$. With this polynomial, $a_n=1$ and $a_i$ is an integer. I have already proven this; I want to see how other people prove it.

Comment: You mean $q\gt 1$. Same proof as irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Multiply everything by $q^n$, you get something like $p^n + q(\text{integer}) = 0 \quad\implies\quad q | p$, a contradiction!

Comment: Showing that $\mathbb Z$ is integrally closed is a special case of the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: Here's a generalization: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/150554/

Comment: @achillehui Wow! your proof is way shorter than mine.

Comment: @Joao, actually, I've a typo in my comment. should be $q|p^n$ instead of $q|p$ but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: @Joao It's the standard proof $\,(a,b) = 1,\ 0 = b^n f(a/b) = a^n + b(\cdots) = 0\,\Rightarrow\,b\mid a^n\,\Rightarrow\, b = 1\,$ by Euclid's Lemma (or unique factorization, or Bezout, etc). For a more general proof that works universally for both gcds and invertible ideals [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/150601/242)