# Show that any rational zero of a polynomial $p\in\Bbb Z[X]$ with $\deg(p)\ge1$ belongs to $a_n^{-1}\Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> Show that any rational zero of a polynomial $p\in\Bbb Z[X]$ with $\deg(p)\ge1$ belongs to $a_n^{-1}\Bbb Z$ (hint: consider $a_n^{n-1}p$.)

Can you check my proof please? I am "almost sure" that it is correct but still I need some confirmation or some comment about how to write it better. Thank you.

---

Let $q\in\Bbb Q$ a zero of $p$ and we will define $z:=a_n^{-1}q$, then we can rewrite the polynomial as

$$\sum_{k=0}^na_kq^k=0\iff z^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_n^{n-1-k}a_kz^k=0\iff z^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kz^k\tag{1}$$

with $c_k=-a_ka_n^{n-1-k}$. If $z\in\Bbb Q\setminus\Bbb Z$ then we can write $z:=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p,q$ are coprime. Then rewriting $(1)$ we get

$$\frac{p^n}{q^n}=\sum c_k \frac{p^k}{q^k}\iff p^n=q^n\sum c_k\frac{p^k}{q^k}\tag{2}$$

where $p,q,c_k\in\Bbb Z$. Then $(2)$ to hold must be the case that $\frac{c_k}{q^k}\in\Bbb Z$ because $p^n,q^n\in\Bbb Z$ but if this is the case we have that $q$ and $p$ are not coprimes, what is a contradiction.

But if $z\in\Bbb Z$ we have that $z^n=\sum c_kz^k$ where for appropriate $c_k$ it is certainly possible, by example take the case

$$z=1\quad\text{and}\quad c_k=(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\quad\text{and}\quad a_n=1$$

Then because $z=a_n^{-1}q$ we can conclude that if $q\in\Bbb Q$ is a zero of $p$ then $q\in a_n^{-1}\Bbb Z$.$\Box$

Comment: $p(q)=0\implies a_nq$ integral over $\mathbb Z\implies a_nq\in\mathbb Z$. (For the last part see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150554/ufds-are-integrally-closed).) And yes, your proof is correct.