# Show that any rational zero of a polynomial $p = \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k X^k \in \mathbb Z [X]$ is in $a_n^{- 1} \mathbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, solution-verification

There is a supposed solution to the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942884/show-that-any-rational-zero-of-a-polynomial-p-in-bbb-zx-with-degp-ge1-b) but that I frankly don't understand what's going on there. I would appreciate feedback as to whether my method is correct.

**Exercise:**

> Show that any rational zero of a polynomial $p = \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k X^k \in \mathbb Z [X]$ of degree $n \geq 1$ is in $a_n^{- 1} \mathbb Z$. (Hint: Consider $a_n^{n - 1}p$.)

**My attempt:**

Taking the hint, we have

\begin{align*}
a_n^{n - 1}p &= a_0 a_n^{n - 1} + a_1 a_n^{n - 2}(a_n X) + a_2 a_n^{n - 3} (a_n X)^2 + \dots + a_{n - 1}(a_n X)^{n - 1} + a_n a_n^{n - 1}X^n\\
&= \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} a_k a_n^{n - 1 - k} (a_nX)^k + (a_nX)^n.
\end{align*}

If we let $Y = a_n X$ then we have a polynomial whose leading coefficient is $1$, and it is known that any rational zero of such a polynomial must be an integer; call it $z \in \mathbb Z$. We therefore have

\begin{align*}
0 &= \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} a_k a_n^{n - 1 - k} z^k + z^n.
\end{align*}

Since $z = a_n x, x \in \mathbb Z$, this implies that $x = a_n^{-1}z$.

Assuming that this is correct, and I'm not quite sure it is, then we have found a zero of $a_n^{n - 1}p$ in terms of $z$. What I need is a zero of $p$ itself in terms of $z$.

Is this method salvageable? I appreciate any help.

(*Analysis I* by Amann and Escher, page 90)

Comment: $cp(z)$ and $p(z)$ have the same zeros for any nonzero constant $c$.

Comment: @TokenToucan Thanks for your help. If I understand correctly, the proof of the fact that $cp(z)$ has the same zeros as $p(z)$ relies on the fact that the ring of integers has no zero divisors, right? Would you say that if I made note of your comment in my proof, then my proof would be complete?