# Every prime ideal of height 1 in a UFD is principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

> If $R$ is a
>   UFD, then every prime ideal of height 1 in $R$ is principal.

I find this is a direct consequence of Kaplansky's theorem. But the proof of Kaplansky's theorem is difficult for me.
 So I wonder how to prove the statement directly.

Comment: Let $P \subset R$ prime ideal and $a \in P$ element not zero. Take an $q$ prime that occurs in decomposition of $a$ and $q \in P$ ($P$ is prime). Then, $P = (q)$, by consideration of height.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Suppose $R$ is a UFD and $P\subset R$ is a height $1$ prime.  Then $P\neq 0$, so there is some nonzero element $x\in P$.  Then $x$ can be written as a product of irreducible elements of $R$.  Since $P$ is a prime ideal, one of those irreducible elements must be in $P$; say $p\in P$ for some irreducible element $p$.  Since $R$ is a UFD, the ideal $(p)$ is prime.  But then $(p)$ is a nonzero prime ideal contained in $P$.  Since $P$ has height $1$, this means $(p)=P$, so $P$ is principal.

Comment: so (0) is considered as a prime ideal since Ufd rings are domains