# Noetherian domain R is a UFD if every prime ideal of height 1 in R is principal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> It is a consequence of a theorem known as Krull’s Hauptidealsatz that
>   every non-unit element in a Noetherian domain is contained in a prime
>   ideal of height 1.
>   **Assuming this,** prove that a Noetherian domain R is a UFD if every prime ideal of height 1 in R is principal.

I want to use the following characterization of UFDs:

1. ACCP holds
2. every irreducible element is prime

The first point is obvious since R is noetherian, but I couldn't prove the second. I do not know whether the way I try is correct or not. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Isn't this obvious? If $q$ is irreducible and contained in a principal prime $(p)$ then $q=pa$. Can you conclude from this?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2548309/every-prime-ideal-of-height-1-in-a-ufd-is-principal).

Comment: could you please elaborte the proof I don't really get to see it

Comment: @VeganMaths added the full proof below

Answer (score 1):

This is based off the solution sketched in the comment but I elaborated here since there was a comment asking for elaboration.

Let $q$ be an irreducible element. By Krull’s Hauptidealsatz (given in the question), $q$ is contained in prime ideal of height 1, which is principal by hypothesis. Write $q \in (p)$, where $p$ is a prime element. Equivalently, $q=pa$ for some $a\in R$. Since $q$ is irreducible, we must have $p$ or $a$ being unit, but $p$ is non-unit. So $a$ is unit.

This makes $q$ a prime element, because $q|xy \Rightarrow p|xy \Rightarrow (p|x \text{ or } p|y) \Rightarrow (q|x \text{ or } q|y)$.