# Integral Elements of $\mathbb{Q[x]}$ in $\mathbb{Q(x)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

So I am wondering which how one can find the integral elements of $\mathbb{Q[x]}$ in its field of fractions $\mathbb{Q(x)}$.

I have shown that $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ is integral iff $p(x) \in \sqrt{<q(x)>}$. Can I give a more complete characterization of the integral closure of $\mathbb{Q[x]}$?

Comment: $\mathbb Q[x]$ is integrally closed.

Comment: Could you explain why is that ?

Comment: You can find this everywhere. Look for UFDs are integrally closed.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150554/ufds-are-integrally-closed.