# What theorem implies this for integer polynomials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $f(x) =x^n-a_1 x^{n-1}+...+(-1)^n a_n \in \mathbb{Z} [X] $. If $-\frac{5}{3}$ is a root of $f$, then $3 |1$.  What theorem implies this and what is the general result?

Comment: This is the [rational root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

Comment: [RRT = Rational Root Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242)   (onsite link)  The Theorem [holds in any GCD domain,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/150601/242) e.g. any UFD.

Comment: Thank you for your help!