# Prove that $x$ is either an integer or irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I prove that if $x$ is a root of the polynomial:
$$x^m+c_1(x^{m-1})+c_2(x^{m-2})+...+c_m=0$$
then $x$ is either an integer or irrational.

- $c_1,c_2,...,c_m$ are all integers

**What I thought:**

Wouldn't it be the same as proving by supposing that $a/b$ is a root of the polynomial, and that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. Plugging into the equation and multiply both sides by $b^m$ then showing that $b$ must be equal to 1.

Comment: That's a good thought.  Have you tried it to see how it works out?

Comment: Do you know the Rational Root Test?

Comment: @BillDubuque Is that the one used in coordinate geometry>

Comment: @abiessu No I haven't tried

Comment: @Sandy Possibly. [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1183042/242) for a few proofs of the Rational Root Test, using Euclid's Lemma or Bezout's gcd Identity and induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going in the right direction.  Suppose $a/b$ is a root of the monic polynomial $f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_0$, whose coefficients are integers, and $a/b$ is written in lowest terms (i.e. $a,b$ coprime).

Then we have $0=f(a/b)=(a/b)^n+a_{n-1}(a/b)^{n-1}+\cdots +a_0$.  By multiplying both sides by $b^n$, we then have $a^n+a_{n-1}ba^{n-1}+\cdots +a_0b^n=0$. By subtracting $a^n$ on both sides, we conclude that $b$ divides $a$, contradicting the assumption that $a/b$ was written in lowest terms if $b\neq \pm 1$.

The same technique can be used to prove the Rational Root Theorem, which states that if we have a polynomial $a_nx^n+\cdots +a_0$ with $a_n\neq 0$ and $a_i$ an integer for each $i$, then if $a/b$ is a rational solution of the polynomial with $a,b$ coprime, then we must have $a| a_0$ and $b| a_n$.

Here's the proof, following in style with the above proof: suppose we have the polynomial $a_nx^n+\cdots +a_0$ with $a_n\neq 0$ and each $a_i$ an integer.  Then if $a/b$ is a rational solution with $a,b$ coprime, we have $a_n(a/b)^n+\cdots+a_0=0$, so by multiplying both sides by $b^n$, we have $a_na^n+ba_{n-1}a^{n-1}+\cdots +a_0b^n=0$.  Subtracting $a_na^n$ on both sides shows that $a_na^n$ is divisible by $b$.  But because $a,b$ are coprime, we find that $a_n$ is divisible by $b$.  Likewise, by subtracting $a_0b^n$ on both sides, we see that $a_0b^n$ is divisible by $a$.  Again, $a,b$ are coprime, so it must be that $a$ divides $a_0$.

The Rational Root theorem also immediately proves our original result, as with $a_n=1$, we must have $b$ divide $a_n$ and hence is $\pm 1$, and so any rational root is an integer.

Comment: RRT can also be proved by induction on degree, e.g. [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1183042/242) and its links. One should  *rigorously* justify why $\,\gcd(a,b)= 1\,$ and $\,b\mid a^n\,$ $\Rightarrow\, b\mid a,\ $ e.g. use Euclid's Lemma or related results.

Comment: @BillDubuque I hadn't seen that proof before, thanks for the link.  And yes, one should, but I'll leave that to the OP. haha