# A "trivial" problem in real analysis

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

Let $k$ be a positive integer and $x=\sqrt{k}$. Suppose $x$ is rational and $x=( \frac{m}{n} )$ such that $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n$ is the least positive integer such that $nx$ is an integer. Define $n'=n(x-[x])$ where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$.

$(a)$ Show that $0\leq n' <n$ and $n'x$ is an integer.

$(b)$ Show that $n'=0$

$(c)$ From $(a)$ and $(b)$, conclude that $\sqrt{k}$ is either a positive integer or irrational.

In this problem, I could establish the inequality using properties of fractional part of x. However, since the question does not mention any such function, I don't think it should be used. Can someone help me solve this.

Comment: you can use division algorithm to write $m = qn + r$

Comment: $(x-[x])$ is the fractional part of $x$ and is $\in [0,1)$

Comment: Since $n$ is positive, $n'=0$ immediately implies that $x$ must be equal to its integer part which is only possible if $x$ is an integer.

Comment: The definition of $n$ ensures that $m$ and $n$ are coprime

Comment: See John Conway's proof in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16544/242) for this method of proof (done slightly more slickly), and follows the links there for much more (see esp. [Theorem 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39769/242) in the 2nd dupe, which is precisely in the form of your exercise, and the discussion there of this form of proof).

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2130828/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2317530/242).

Comment: If you read the linked proofs, you will see how the proof can be viewed as a *descent* on the denominators for $x$, i.e. the arguments show that if $n>1$ is a denominator for $x$ (i.e. $nx\in\Bbb Z)\,$ then  $x$ can also be written with a smaller denominator $n'.\,$ This yields a  contradiction if the least denom $n$ is $> 1\,$ (or, equivalently, it yields an infinite descent on denominators $\, \ldots n'' < n' < n,\,$ contra $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered). Thus the least denom must be $\,n=1,\,$ i.e. $\,x\in\Bbb Z\ \ $

Comment: If anything remains unclear please post further comments (either here or on the linked answers).