# Irrationality $\sqrt{2}$ with ideal

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, irrational-numbers

How can I prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational with the ideal $$\{n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid n\times \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb Z\}?$$

Comment: Just show that there cannot exist a minimum element in the set that can be an integer.

Comment: Which ring is that an ideal in?

Comment: thanks for your answer, math buddy. But you see, my point IS to prove that the ideal is reduced to zéro. Because the Z is principal, so all the ideals have the same structure, e.g. (k)={nk| n \in N}. Get it ?

Comment: Yes, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2941/242) in the linked dupe (and its links).

Comment: thanks !!! That's exactly wot I was searching.