# irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ with ring theory

Tags: ring-theory, irrational-numbers, principal-ideal-domains

I consider the ideal $I \subseteq \Bbb Z$ with $I=\{n \in \Bbb Z \mid n \times \sqrt{2} \in \Bbb Z\}$. I do not manage to prove that this ideal is trivial. Can you help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988930/irrationality-sqrt2-with-ideal)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Irrationality $\sqrt{2}$ with ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988930/irrationality-sqrt2-with-ideal)

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1311228/what-is-the-most-unusual-proof-you-know-that-sqrt2-is-irrational?noredirect=1&lq=1).