# Show that if $p$ is prime then $p\neq (a/b)^2$ for any integers $a$ and $b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Question**:

> Show that if $p$ is prime then $p\neq (a/b)^2$ for any integers $a$ and $b$

Comment: This is not abstract algebra, it is elementary number theory. Also, please use MathJax to typeset your question. [Here is a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: If $p$ is prime, then $p$ must be an integer. It follows that $\frac ab$ must also be an integer. Can $z^2$ be prime if $z\in\mathbb Z$?

Comment: What do you know about prime factorization? If $\frac {a^2}{b^2} = p$ is an integer the $b^2$ divides evenly into $a^2$.  What does that say about the factor of $b$ and the factors of $a$.  What if you divide out the common factors of $a^2$ and $b^2$?  What does that leave us?

Comment: Do you know whether fractions can be expressed in lowest terms?

Comment: @doobdood It follows that $\frac {a^2}{b^2}$ is and integer and that $b^2$ divides evenly into $a^2$.  But does that mean $b$ divides evenly into $a$?  What can we assume the OP knows and can assume?  I think the OP needs to decide if $b^2$ divides evenly into $a^2$ what that says about the factors of $a$ and $b$ and what we can conclude about whether $a$ and $b$ is an integer. But saying "if $\frac ab \not \in \mathbb Z$ then $\frac {a^2}{b^2} \not \in \mathbb Z$" is pretty much the whole point of what we need to prove.

Comment: We already have hundreds of answers on the irrationality of square-roots. See the linked thread (and their links) for most of the common proofs. Please search first to avoid posting dupe questions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use a proof by contradiction.

Assume for the sake of contradiction that there exists a prime $p$ such that $p=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$. This implies that $\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ is an integer, and since $a,b$ are integers, so is $\frac{a}{b}$. Let $\frac{a}{b}=k$. We know that $p=k^2$. However, we have a contradiction because both $k$ and $k^2$ divide $p$ (unless $k=k^2$, in which case $p=1$, which is not prime). We're done! $\blacksquare$

Comment: This argument is either incorrect (circular) or incomplete without justification of the key claim that $\,(a/b)^2\in \Bbb Z\Rightarrow a/b\in \Bbb Z.\,$ See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4572/242) for much further discussion of this point.

Answer (score 0):

Note that each fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ has an irreducible representation, that is, there exist $a_{1},b_{1}$ such that $\frac{a}{b} =\frac{a_{1}}{b_{1}}$ and $\gcd(a_{1},b_{1}) = 1$.

So if $p = (\frac{a}{b})^{2}$, then $p = (\frac{a_{1}}{b_{1}})^{2}=\frac{a_{1}^{2}}{b_{1}^{2}} \implies b_{1}^{2}p = a_1{}^{2} \implies p \mid a_{1}^{2} \implies p \mid a_{1}.$

Similarly $p \mid b_{1} \implies p \mid a_{1},b_{1} \implies (a_{1},b_{1})  \neq 1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Clearer conceptually to compare power of power of $2$ in unique prime factorization of $\, a^2 = p b^2,\,$ yielding LHS has even power vs. RHS has odd power, contra uniqueness. This can be simplfied to use only [uniqueness of power of $2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1317951/242)

Answer (score 0):

Let
$v_p(k)$ be the exponent of
the largest power of $p$
that divides $k$
so that
$p^{v_p(k)} | k$
and
$p^{v_p(k)+1} \not\mid k$.

Then
if $m, a, b \ge 1$
then $ m |v_p((a/b)^m)$.

This problem is the case
$m = 2$.

Proof.

If
$ v_p((a/b)^m) = n$
where $n \ge 1$,
let
$v_p(a) = u$
and
$v_p(b) = v$
where $u, v \ge 0$.

Then
$v_p(a/b) = u-v$
so
$v_p((a/b)^m) = m(u-v)$
so
$n = m(u-v)
$.

Therefore
$m | n$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you know about factorization.

Do you know every number has a unique prime factorization?  If you know that then you know that if $p = \frac{a^2}{b^2}$ and $p$ is an integer,  then $b^2$ divides evenly into $a^2$ and the primes that divide into $b$ also divide into $a$ but to higher power and the powers that divide into $b^2$ and $a^2$ are the same that divide into $b$ and $a$ but to exactly half the powers. So if $b^2$ divides evenly into $a^2$ then $b$ divides evenly into $a$ and $\frac ab$ is an integer.  SO $p = \frac{a^2}{b^2} = (\frac ab)^2$ and so $p$ is a perfect square. .... but $p$ is prime.  SO that's impossible.

But knowing the every number has a unique prime factorization is a pretty sophisticated assumption?  Maybe you aren't allowed to assume it.

BUt can you assume that $\frac ab$ can be written in "lowest terms"?  If $\frac ab$  is in lowest terms then $a$ and $b$ have no factors in common.  Does that mean that $a^2$ and $b^2$ have no factors in common?  That depends on what you know.  But if $a^2$ and $b^2$ have  no factors in common then $b^2$ can't divide evenly into $a^2$ (unless we assume $b = 1$) and we cant have $\frac {a^2}{b^2}= p$ an integer.

Is it possible that $\frac ab$ is not in "lowest terms"?  If $a,b$ have a factor $k$ in common then $\frac ab = \frac {\frac ak}{\frac bk}$ and we can do this for all factors.  Is there always a finite number of factors and we will eventually factor them all out until we get $\frac ab = \frac {a'}{b'}$ where $a', b'$ don't have factors in common?  THe only other option would be if $a$ and $b$ both have an infinite number of factors in common and that's just plain nutty.

But do we *know* this stuff?

If $a,b$ have no factors in common than neither to $a^2, b^2$ so we can't have $\frac {a^2}{b^2} = p$ as in integer.... unless..... is it possible that somehow squaring $a$ and squaring $b$ add a new factor out of nowhere.  That's *kinda* *sorta* what the ancient pythagorians wanted to sweep under the rug.

DO we know that's impossible?  Do we know Euclid's Lemma?  If we have $p = \frac {a^2}{b^2}$ then $pa^2 = b^2$ so $p$ divides evenly into $a^2$. But $p$ is prime and indivisible.  Does that mean we can't split up $p$ among the two copies of $a$ in $a\times a = a^2$?  Does that mean $p$ must divide evenly into $a$?

But if $p$ divides evenly into $a$ that would mean $p^2$ divides into $a^2$, wouldn't it?  And if $pb^2 = a^2$ and $p^2$ divides $a^2$ the we can divide both sides by $p^2$ and get that $p$ divides evenly into $b^2$.  But that means $p$ divides $b$ for the same reason and $a, b$ have $p$ as common factor....

SO....  what do we know about factorization?  Which of those observations are legitimate?  What can we conclude?