# $q\mid 2^p-1\Rightarrow p\mid q-1$ [order divides prime $p \Rightarrow$ order $= p$ or $1$]

Tags: number-theory, abstract-algebra, prime-numbers

I've just come up with this question as I'm studying for a number theory midterm. If $p$ and $q$ are different prime numbers, and it's known that $2^p \equiv 1 \bmod{q}$, then $q\equiv 1 \bmod{p}$. I've tried a few cases and it seems to be true. How can it be proved?

Comment: Let $k$ be minimal natural number, such that $2^k\equiv 1\mod{q}$. Then its easy to see that $k|p$ and $k|(q-1)$(from the little theorem of Fermat). But, because $p$ is prime, there just 2 cases:

1)$k=1$ - impossible.

2)$k=p\to p|(q-1)$

Comment: That was neat. болшое спасибо, Такенов.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/719321/242) $\!\bmod q\!:\ 2^p,\, 2^{q-1}\! \equiv 1 \Rightarrow 2^{\gcd(p,q-1)}\! \equiv 1\Rightarrow\,$ $\overbrace{\gcd(\color{#c00}p,\,q\!-\!1) = \color{#c00}p}^{\textstyle \Rightarrow\ p\mid q\!-\!1\ }\, $ (not $\color{#c00}1$ else $\rm \,q\mid 2^{\color{#c00}1}\!-1$)

---

**Or** $\!\bmod q\!:\ 2^p\equiv 1\ \,\smash[t]{\overset{\rm\color{#0a0}m}\Rightarrow}\,\ 2\,$ has $\:\!\color{#c00}{\rm order }\,k\mid p\Rightarrow k = \color{#c00}p\; $ (not $\color{#c00}1$ else $\rm \,q\mid 2^{\color{#c00}1}\!-1)\,$ so by little Fermat $\ \bmod q\!:\,\ 2^{q-1}\equiv 1^{\phantom{|^|}}\smash[t]{\overset{\rm\color{#0a0}{m}}\Rightarrow}\,\  \color{#c00}p\mid q-1,\,$ by $\,\rm\color{#0a0}{m} =\,$ [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) (or [this Corollary](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242)).

Said in group theory language: $ $ if $\,g\ne 1$ has order *dividing* a prime $\,p\,$ then it has order *equal* $p.\,$ In ring theory language: if a principal ideal$\;\ne 1$ contains an irreducible element then that element generates the ideal (that's why a minimal polynomial is often called the "irreducible polynomial"). $ $ Here the group / ideal is simply the so-called **order ideal** $\,\{n : x^n = 1 \},\,$ which, being nonempty and closed under subtraction, comprises a subgroup / ideal of $\:\mathbb Z.\,$ The Euclidean algorithm implies that ideals in $\mathbb Z$ are principal, so every element of a nonzero ideal is a multiple of the least positive element. For an order ideal this simply says that every "possible" order is a multiple of the least possible order $\, m,\ $  i.e. $\; x^n = 1 \,\Rightarrow\, m\mid n.\,$ Compare this ring-theoretic proof to the ubiquitous group-theoretic proof using Lagrange's theorem.

*Additive* example of an order ideal: $ $ a **denominator ideal** $\ \{n\, :\, nx \in \mathbb Z \,\}$ of a fraction $\,x\in\Bbb Q.\,$ Here the above yields: if a proper fraction can be written with a prime denominator then it is the least possible denominator (in the multiplicative sense), i.e. it divides every other denominator.

Denominator ideals and fractional ideals can yield significant number-theoretical simplifications - in much the same way that fractional arithmetic often serves to simplify integer arithmetic in elementary number theory. For example, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491) on irrationality proofs using the denominator ideal. More generally, see [this proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30313) employing Dedekind's [conductor ideal] - a  universal denominator for an entire extension ring. The links elaborate on tis topic.