# Prove that $\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\gcd(n, m)} - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility, ideals, gcd-and-lcm

For all $a, m, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$,

$$\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\gcd(n, m)} - 1$$

Comment: Another question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/gcdbx-1-by-1-b-z-1-b-gcdx-y-z-1) was closed as a duplicate of this one where there is a second solution.

Comment: Find here: [Number Theory for Mathematical Contests](http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~lavric/Santos%20-%20Number%20Theory%20for%20Mathematical%20Contests.pdf), Example#245, Page#36.

Comment: And what  if we consider GCD over $\mathbb{C} [X] $?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee hey i know it's been 8 years but I just stumbled upon this post and I found that link quite interesting. Do you have more of that kind of material (mathematical contests)?

Comment: @NotAMathematician, See  https://www.pdfdrive.com/104-number-theory-problems-from-the-training-of-the-usa-imo-team-e162936488.html and  https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~lavric/

Comment: Isn't there some sort of useful pathway to solve this using the Fibonacci numbers. For instance, when we use the division lemma, we get that the remainder at the $k$th iteration is $r_{k}=a^{(-1)^{k-1}mF_{k}-nF_{k+1}}$?

Answer (score 90):

Mimic in expts a *subtractive* Euclidean algorithm $\rm\,(n,m) = (\color{#0a0}{n\!-\!m},m)$

$$\begin{align} \rm{e.g.}\ \ &\rm (f_5,f_2) = (f_3,f_2) = (f_1,f_2) = (f_1,f_1) = (f_1,\color{darkorange}{f_0})= f_1 = f_{\:\!(5,\,2)}\\[.3em]
{\rm like}\ \ \ &(5,\ 2)\, =\:\! (3,\ 2)\, =\:\! (1,\ 2)\:\! =\:\! (1,\ 1)\:\! =\:\! (1,\ \color{darkorange}0)\:\! = 1,\ \ {\rm since}\end{align}\qquad$$

$\rm\ f_{\,n}\: :=\ a^n\!-\!1\ =\ a^{n-m} \: \color{#c00}{(a^m\!-\!1)} + \color{#0a0}{a^{n-m}\!-\!1},\,\ $  hence $\rm\:\ {f_{\,n}\! = \color{#0a0}{f_{\,n-m}}\! + k\ \color{#c00}{f_{\,m}}},\,\ k\in\mathbb Z,\:$  thus

**Theorem** $\: $ If $\rm\ f_{\, n}\: $ is an integer sequence with $\rm\ \color{darkorange}{f_{0} =\, 0},\: $ $\rm \:{ f_{\,n}\!\equiv \color{#0a0}{f_{\,n-m}}\ (mod\ \color{#c00}{f_{\,m})}}\ $ for all $\rm\: n > m,\ $  then $\rm\: (f_{\,n},f_{\,m})\ =\ f_{\,(n,\:m)}, \: $ where $\rm\ (i,\:j)\ $ denotes $\rm\ gcd(i,\:j).\:$

**Proof** $\ $ By induction on  $\rm\:n + m\:$. The theorem is trivially true if $\rm\ n = m\ $ or $\rm\ n = \color{darkorange}0\ $ or $\rm\: m = \color{darkorange}0.\:$
So we may assume $\rm\:n > m > 0\:$.$\ $  Note $\rm\ (f_{\,n},f_{\,m}) = (\color{#0a0}{f_{\,n-m}},\color{#c00}{f_{\,m}})\ $ follows by $\rm\color{#90f}{Euclid}$ & hypothesis.
Since $\rm\ (n-m)+m \ <\ n+m,\ $ induction yields $\rm\, \ (f_{\,n-m},f_{\,m})\, =\, f_{\,(n-m,\:m)} =\, f_{\,(n,\:m)}.$

$\rm\color{#90f}{Euclid}\!:\ A\equiv a\pmod{\! m}\,\Rightarrow\ (A,m) = (a,m)\,$ is the reduction (descent) step used above and in the Euclidean algorithm $\rm\: (A,m) = (A\bmod m,\,m),\, $ i.e. the special case $\,\rm f_{\:\!n} = n\,$ above.

This is a prototypical [strong divisibility sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence). Same [for Fibonacci numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60353/242)

---

**Alternatively** it has a natural proof by the [Order Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) $\ a^k\equiv 1\iff {\rm ord}(a)\mid k,\,$ viz.

$$\begin{eqnarray}\ {\rm mod}\:\ d\!:\  a^M\!\equiv 1\equiv a^N&\!\iff\!& {\rm ord}(a)\ |\ M,N\!\color{#c00}\iff\! {\rm ord}(a)\ |\ (M,N)\!\iff\! \color{#0a0}{a^{(M,N)}\!\equiv 1}\\[.3em]
 {\rm i.e.}\ \ \ d\ |\ a^M\!-\!1,\:a^N\!-\!1\! &\!\iff\!\!&\ d\ |\ \color{#0a0}{a^{(M,N)}\!-\!1},\qquad\,\ {\rm where} \quad\! (M,N)\, :=\, \gcd(M,N)
\end{eqnarray}\ \ \ \ \ $$

Thus, by above $\, a^M\!-\!1,\:a^N\!-\!1\ $ and $\, a^{(M,N)}\!-\!1\ $  have the same set $\,S\,$ of *common* divisors $\,d,\, $ hence they have the same *greatest* common divisor $\ (= \max\ S).$

**Note** $ $ We  used the GCD [universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88411/242)  $\ a\mid b,c \color{#c00}\iff a\mid (b,c)\ $ [which is the *definition* of a gcd in more general rings]. $ $ Compare that with $\ a<b,c \!\iff\! a< \min(b,c),\, $ and, analogously, $\,\  a\subset b,c\iff a\subset b\cap c.\ $ Such universal "iff" characterizations enable quick and easy simultaneous proof of *both* directions - just like above.

The conceptual structure at the core of this simple proof is the ubiquitous **order ideal.** $\ $ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/if-the-order-divides-a-prime-p-then-the-order-is-p-or-1/4715#4715) for more on this and the more familiar additive form of a **denominator ideal.**

Comment: Sort of like the Fibonacci sequence!

Comment: @john Yes, they are both [strong divisibility sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence), i.e. $\,(f_n,f_m) = f_{(n,m)}.\,$ [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/60353/242) for the Fibonacci case.

Answer (score 37):

Below is a proof which has the neat feature that it immediately specializes
to a proof of the integer Bezout identity for $\rm\:x = 1,\:$ allowing us to view it as a [q-analog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog) of the integer case.

E.g. for $\rm\ m,n\ =\ 15,21$

$\rm\displaystyle\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \frac{x^3-1}{x-1}\ =\ (x^{15}\! +\! x^9\! +\! 1)\ \frac{x^{15}\!-\!1}{x\!-\!1} - (x^9\!+\!x^3)\ \frac{x^{21}\!-\!1}{x\!-\!1}$

for  $\rm\ x = 1\ $  specializes to  $\ 3\ \ =\  \ 3\ (15)\ \ -\ \ 2\ (21)\:,\ $ i.e. $\rm\ (3)\ =\ (15,21) := gcd(15,21)$

**Definition** $\rm\displaystyle \quad n' \: :=\ \frac{x^n - 1}{x-1}\:$. $\quad$ **Note** $\rm\quad  n' = n\ $  for  $\rm\ x = 1$.

**Theorem** $\rm\quad (m',n')\ =\ ((m,n)')\ $ as ideals in $\rm\,\Bbb Z[x],\,$for naturals $\rm\:m,n.$

**Proof** $\ $ It is trivially true if $\rm\ m = n\ $  or  if  $\rm\ m = 0\ $  or  $\rm\ n = 0.\:$

W.l.o.g. suppose  $\rm\:n > m > 0.\:$ We proceed by induction on  $\rm\:n\! +\! m.$

$\begin{eqnarray}\rm   &\rm x^n\! -\! 1 &=&\ \rm  x^r\ (x^m\! -\! 1)\  +\  x^r\! -\! 1 \quad\ \ \rm for\ \  r = n\! -\! m \\[.1em]  
\quad\Rightarrow\quad\! &\rm\qquad n' &=&\ \rm  x^r\ m'\ +\ r' \quad\ \ \rm by\ dividing\ above\ by\ \ x\!-\!1 \\
\quad\Rightarrow\ \  &\rm  (m', n')\, &=&\  \rm (m', r') \\
 & &=&\rm   ((m,r)') \quad\ \ by\ induction, applicable\ by\:\  m\!+\!r = n < n\!+\!m \\[.1em]
 & &=&\rm   ((m,n)') \quad\ \:\! by\ \  r \equiv n\ \:(mod\ m)\quad\ \ \bf\small QED
\end{eqnarray}$

**Corollary** $\ $ Integer Bezout Theorem $\ $ **Proof:** $ $ set $\rm\ x = 1\ $ above, i.e. erase primes.

A deeper understanding comes when one studies Divisibility Sequences
and Divisor Theory.

Comment: Is $((\rm m,n)')$ supposed to be $((\rm m,n))'$ i.e. $\rm \dfrac{x^{(m,n)}-1}{x-1}$?

Comment: @Peter $ $ Let $\rm\:(m,n)' = \dfrac{x^{\,(m,n)}\!-\!1}{x\!-\!1} =: f.\:$ Then $\rm\:((m,n)') = (f) = f\:\mathbb Z[x]\:$ is a principal ideal, thus the equality $\rm\:(m',n') = ((m,n)')\:$ denotes the ideal equality $\rm\:(g,h) = (f)\:$ for polynomials $\rm\:f,g,h\in\mathbb Z[x].\:$ If you have no knowledge of ideals you can instead simply interpret it as saying that $\rm\:f\:|\:g,h\:$ and $\rm\:f = a\,g+b\,h\:$ for some $\rm\:a,b\in \mathbb Z[x],\:$ which implies $\rm\:f = gcd(g,h).$

Answer (score 25):

Let $m\ge n\ge 1$. Apply Euclidean Algorithm.

$\gcd\left(a^m-1,a^n-1\right)=\gcd\left(a^{n}\left(a^{m-n}-1\right),a^n-1\right)$. Since $\gcd(a^n,a^n-1)=1$, we get

$\gcd\left(a^{m-n}-1,a^n-1\right)$. Iterate this until it becomes $$\gcd\left(a^{\gcd(m,n)}-1,a^{\gcd(m,n)}-1\right)=a^{\gcd(m,n)}-1$$

Comment: And this too is a duplicate of an [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/11570/242) in the 5-year-old linked  duplicate thread.

Answer (score 24):

Let
$$\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = t$$
then
$$a^n \equiv 1 \pmod t\,\quad\text{and}\quad\,a^m \equiv 1 \,\pmod t$$
And thus
$$a^{nx + my} \equiv 1\, \pmod t$$
$\forall\,x,\,y\in \mathbb{Z}$

According to the *[Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)*, we have
$$nx + my =\gcd(n,m)$$
This follows
$$a^{nx + my} \equiv 1\pmod t \implies a^{\gcd(n,m)} \equiv 1 \pmod t\implies  t\big|\big( a^{\gcd(n,m)} - 1\big) $$

Therefore
$$a^{\gcd(m,n)}-1\, =\gcd(a^m-1, a^n-1) $$

Since it is easy to show $(a^{\gcd(n,m)}-1)\big|t$.

Comment: I don't understand why you can conclude that $(a^{\gcd(n,m)}-1)\mid t$ from $a^{\gcd(n,m)}\equiv 1\pmod t$. The latter will give you $t\mid (a^{\gcd(n,m)}-1)\ $.

Comment: How did you manage to conclude, which would require that $k=1$: $$a^{\gcd(m,n)}-1\, =\gcd(a^m-1, a^n-1) $$

Comment: To prove $(a^{\gcd(n,m)}-1)\big|t$, I would try to show that $(a^{\gcd(n,m)}-1)$ divides both $(a^{m}-1)$ and $(a^{n}-1)$. As it is a common divisor, it must divide their greatest common divisor, $t$.

Answer (score 13):

More generally, if $\gcd(a,b)=1$, $a,b,m,n\in\mathbb Z^+$, $a> b$, then $$\gcd(a^m-b^m,a^n-b^n)=a^{\gcd(m,n)}-b^{\gcd(m,n)}$$

Proof: Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, we get $\gcd(b,d)=1$, so $b^{-1}\bmod d$ exists.

$$d\mid a^m-b^m, a^n-b^n\iff \left(ab^{-1}\right)^m\equiv \left(ab^{-1}\right)^n\equiv 1\pmod{d}$$

$$\iff \text{ord}_{d}\left(ab^{-1}\right)\mid m,n\iff \text{ord}_{d}\left(ab^{-1}\right)\mid \gcd(m,n)$$

$$\iff \left(ab^{-1}\right)^{\gcd(m,n)}\equiv 1\pmod{d}\iff a^{\gcd(m,n)}\equiv b^{\gcd(m,n)}\pmod{d}$$

Comment: This is precisely the [homogenization](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20301/how-to-know-that-a3b3-aba2-abb2/20332#20332)  $(a^n-1\to a^n-b^n)$  of a [proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/11636/242) in the 5-year-old duplicate thread linked in Yuan's comment on the question. To avoid posting such duplicate answers it's a good ides to first peruse duplicate links before posting an answer to a five year old question!

Comment: Update: actually this homegenized version was posted 5 months prior in [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1217689/242). There are probably older dupes too since this is a FAQ. Posting the link in case anyone decides to organize.

Comment: I didn't understand why if gcd$(a,b) =1$ then gcd$(b, d) =1$? and why $\left(ab^{-1}\right)^m\equiv \left(ab^{-1}\right)^n\equiv 1\pmod{d}$?

Answer (score 11):

More generally, if $a,b,m,n\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 1}$, $a>b$ and $(a,b)=1$ (as usual, $(a,b)$ denotes $\gcd(a,b)$), then  $$(a^m-b^m,a^n-b^n)=a^{(m,n)}-b^{(m,n)}$$

**Proof:** Use $\,x^k-y^k=(x-y)(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}y+\cdots+xy^{k-2}+x^{k-1})\,$

and use $n\mid a,b\iff n\mid (a,b)$ to prove:

$a^{(m,n)}-b^{(m,n)}\mid a^m-b^m,\, a^n-b^n\iff$

$a^{(m,n)}-b^{(m,n)}\mid (a^m-b^m,a^n-b^n)=: d\ \ \ (1)$

$a^m\equiv b^m,\, a^n\equiv b^n$ mod $d$ by definition of $d$.

[Bezout's lemma](https://www.google.lt/search?dcr=0&source=hp&q=bezout%27s+lemma&oq=bezout%27s+lemma&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i19k1l3j0i22i30i19k1.298.1782.0.1854.15.11.0.0.0.0.254.971.0j4j2.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..9.6.968.0..0j35i39k1j0i131k1.ULZfBRkOWaE) gives $\,mx+ny=(m,n)\,$ for some $x,y\in\Bbb Z$.

$(a,b)=1\iff (a,d)=(b,d)=1$, so $a^{mx},b^{ny}$ mod $d$ exist (notice $x,y$ can be negative).

$a^{mx}\equiv b^{mx}$, $a^{ny}\equiv b^{ny}$ mod $d$.

$a^{(m,n)}\equiv a^{mx}a^{ny}\equiv b^{mx}b^{ny}\equiv b^{(m,n)}\pmod{\! d}\ \ \ (2)$

$(1)(2)\,\Rightarrow\, a^{(m,n)}-b^{(m,n)}=d$

Answer (score 9):

Written for [a duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2690987/gcd-of-two-big-numbers), this may be a bit more elementary than the other answers here, so I will post it:

---

If $g=(a,b)$ and $G=\left(p^a-1,p^b-1\right)$, then
$$
\left(p^g-1\right)\sum_{k=0}^{\frac ag-1}p^{kg}=p^a-1\tag1
$$
and
$$
\left(p^g-1\right)\sum_{k=0}^{\frac bg-1}p^{kg}=p^b-1\tag2
$$
Thus, we have that
$$
\left.p^g-1\,\middle|\,G\right.\tag3
$$

---

For $x\ge0$,
$$
\left(p^a-1\right)\sum_{k=0}^{x-1}p^{ak}=p^{ax}-1\tag4
$$
Therefore, we have that
$$
\left.G\,\middle|\,p^{ax}-1\right.\tag5
$$
If $\left.G\,\middle|\,p^{ax-b(y-1)}-1\right.$, then 
$$
\left.G\,\middle|\,\left(p^{ax-b(y-1)}-1\right)-p^{ax-by}\left(p^b-1\right)\right.=p^{ax-by}-1\tag6
$$
Therefore, by induction on $y$ (with $(5)$ as the base case and $(6)$ as the inductive step), for any $x,y\ge0$ so that $ax-by\ge0$,
$$
\left.G\,\middle|\,p^{ax-by}-1\right.\tag7
$$
which means that
$$
\left.G\,\middle|\,p^g-1\right.\tag8
$$

---

Putting all this together gives
$$
G=p^g-1\tag9
$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on the step $if G \mid p^{ax-(b-1)y}$. How you arrived on this term.

Comment: That was a typo. Thanks for noticing it. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Why you are using "if....". What if, "if..."  doesn't hold true

Comment: It does in the case of $y=1$ due to the preceding line. The subsequent lines finish the induction.

Comment: I feel you should mention the induction argument more clearly. After you edited solution, it appears inductive in nature. Still some more clarity will be helpful.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Apology for adding Answer(Already lot of answers)

It's a beautiful question

In fact, I tried to check on computer.(When I didn't know Bezout's Identity)

I tried to prove as:

Let d = gcd($a^m-1, a^n-1$)

implies: $a^m ≡ 1 $  $mod(d)$ and $a^n ≡  1$  $mod(d)$

Now, $gcd(m,n) = mx+ny$    .........**#Bezout's Identity**

$a^{gcd(m, n)} ≡ a^{(mx+ny)} ≡  a^{mx}a^{ny} ≡ 1 $  $mod(d)$

Therefore, $ d |a^{gcd(m,n)} −1.$ We now show that $a^{gcd(m,n)} −1 |d.$
Since gcd(m,n) |m, we have

$a^{gcd(m,n)} −1 |a^m −1$     .....#1

Similarly,
$a^{gcd(m,n)} −1 |a^n −1$     .....#2

Since, $a^{gcd(m, n)}-1$ divides both $a^m-1$ and $a^n-1$ so it must also divide their GCD :

$a^{gcd(m, n)}-1| gcd(a^m-1, a^n-1) $ ≡ $mod(d)$

Since, $d |a^{gcd(m,n)}−1$ and $a^{gcd(m,n)}−1 |d$, we must have $d = gcd(a^m−1,a^n−1)$ =
$a^{gcd(m,n)} −1$

So, Bezout's Identity makes the proof simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Besides excellent answers above, you can use a property that

$\gcd((y+1)x, y)= \gcd(x,y)$

where $x=a^m - 1, y = a^n - 1$ to find the proof.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to check that if $(m,n) = 1$ then the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant)

$$R_{m,n} \colon =\operatorname{res}(\frac{x^m-1}{x-1}, \frac{x^n-1}{x-1}) = 1$$

Now we have

$$R_{m,n} = \prod_{\xi^n=1, \xi \ne 1} \frac{\xi^m-1}{\xi-1}$$

Now, since $(m,n) = 1$, the map $\xi \mapsto \xi^m$ is a bijection of $\{\xi^n=1, \xi \ne 1\}$. We conclude that $R_{m,n} = 1$.