# Show that $\gcd(2^m-1, 2^n-1) = 2^ {\gcd(m,n)} -1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that $\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\gcd(n, m)} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1)
>   [$\gcd(b^x - 1, b^y - 1, b^ z- 1,&hellip;) = b^{\gcd(x, y, z,&hellip;)} -1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/gcdbx-1-by-1-b-z-1-b-gcdx-y-z-1)

I'm trying to figure this out:

Show that for all positive integers $m$ and $n$

$\gcd(2^m-1, 2^n-1) = 2^{\gcd(m,n)} -1$

I appreciate your help,
Thanks.

***Note:*** $\gcd$ stands for the greatest common divisor.

Comment: Can you at least show that $2^{\gcd(m,n)}-1$ is a common divisor of $2^m-1$ and $2^n-1$? That’s actually fairly easy to see if you write all three numbers in binary.

Comment: Here is the general case from another question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/prove-that-gcdan-1-am-1-a-gcdn-m-1

Comment: Qiaochu Yuan’s solution of the general case [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/gcdbx-1-by-1-b-z-1-b-gcdx-y-z-1/11570#11570) is probably more readable than those at the question that Gbean found.

Comment: It may be useful to write $(m,n)$ as $am+bn$ where $a,b$ are integers.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225289