# Prove if $p∣m$ then $2^p−1∣2^m-1$

Tags: proof-writing, divisibility

Prove if $p∣m$ then $2^p−1∣2^m-1.$

I need this to understand this:

> In general, if $p=\gcd(m,n)$ then $p=mx+ny$ for some integers $x,y$.
>
> Now, if $d = \gcd(2^m-1,2^n-1)$ then $2^m \equiv 1 \pmod d$ and $2^n \equiv 1\pmod d$ so $$2^p = 2^{mx+ny} = (2^m)^x(2^n)^y \equiv 1 \pmod d$$
>
> So $d\mid 2^p-1$.
>
> On the other hand, if $p\mid m$ then $2^p-1\mid 2^m-1$ so $2^p-1$ is a common factor.
>
> And yes, you can replace $2$ with any $a$.

In this context. [Proving that $\gcd(2^m - 1, 2^n - 1) = 2^{\gcd(m,n )} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225289/proving-that-gcd2m-1-2n-1-2-gcdm-n-1)

Comment: What specifically are you not understanding?

Comment: I do not understand why if $p|m$ then $2^p-1|2^m-1$, where it comes from at all.

Comment: So $m=pn$ and you are wondering why $a^{n}\equiv1\pmod{a-1}$ where $a=2^p$?

Comment: $a^k-1=(a-1)(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}+\cdots+1)\,$. So, if $m=kp$ then $2^m-1=\left(2^{p}\right)^k-1=(2^p-1)(\dots)$.

Comment: If it looks reasonable to you that $111$ (three ones) is a divisor of $111111111111111$ (fifteen ones), it should not come as a surprise that $2^3-1$ is a divisor of $2^{15}-1$: just think to base-2 representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to visualize it is to set  $2^p=a$ and $m=kp $. In this way we are left with the trivial result

$$a−1∣a^k-1$$

Comment: Don't you mean $m=kp$?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.