# Algebra(Euclid method)

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I couldn’t solve this question and I don’t know how to figure this out from beginning.
Hint from my school was to think about euclid method on $ α^m-1,α^n-1$,and better to think $α$ as Polynomial.
Here is the question

***There are  positive integer m,n and $gcd(m, n) = d$ .
At this time, show that

$gcd (a^m -1,a^n −1) = a^d −1$ is valid for 2 or more integer a.***

Comment: cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225289/proving-that-gcd2m-1-2n-1-2-gcdm-n-1)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $\quad gcd (a^m -1,a^n −1) = a^d −1\quad$ we begin by showing

$$a^n-1=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+a^{n-3}+ ...+a^{0})$$
This is true no matter what the power of $a$ so $(a-1)$ is a divisor of any such variable or function. As we can see, however, the cofactor contains $n$ terms with the highest being $a^{n-1}$ so the GCD of the cofactors is $1$. This means that the only divisor of any $(a^x-1)$ is $(a-1)$ or its cofactor for any power $x$.
$$\therefore GCD(a^m-1,a^n-1)=(a-1)\text{ where } a,m,n\in\mathbb{N}\text{ i.e. 
 they natural numbers}$$
The rest is merely showing that $a=a^d$ where $d=0$.