# Prove that if $n$ and $m$ are coprime then $2^n-1$ and $2^m-1$ respectively are coprime too

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

How to prove that if $n$ and $m$ are coprime then  $2^n-1$ and $2^m-1$  are coprime too?
I tried with Bezout's identity without results.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Check out [Proving that $\gcd(2^m - 1, 2^n - 1) = 2^{\gcd(m,n )} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/225289/602049).

Answer (score 0):

Show that $\gcd(2^n-1, 2^m-1) = 2^{\gcd(m, n)} - 1 = 2^1-1= 1$.