# Simple Mersenne prime divisibility proofs

Tags: elementary-number-theory

From "Fundamentals of Number Theory" by William J. LeVeque:

> $M_n=2^n-1$.
>
> Show that if $n=rs$, $M_r$ divides $M_n$.

My proof is:

> $(M_n=2^n-1)+(n=rs) => (M_{rs}=2^{rs}-1)=>(M_{rs}=(2^r)^s-1)$
>
> $(M_r=2^r-1)=>(M_r+1=2^r)$
>
> $M_{rs}=(M_r+1)^s-1$
>
> In the expansion of $(M_r+1)^s$, all components are of the form $M_rX$, except for the product of all ones. This follows from the combinatorial constraints. Therefore $M_n$ is of the form
>
> $M_n=M_{rs}=M_r(X_1+X_2+...)+1-1$.
>
> Thus $M_r|M_n$.

---

I have two questions:

1) Is this proof correct/acceptable?

2) In what *other* ways can this problem be solved? Specifically I am interested in what other kinds of algebraic/logical/mathematical manipulations could be used.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The proof is good, very clear. I would prefer a few more words. Note that  $+$ is not a common abbreviation of the logical connective "and."

Comment: @André I'll keep those things in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $\rm\ f_n\! :=\ a^n\!-1\ =\ a^{n-m} \: (a^m\!-1) + a^{n-m}\!-1\:$,$\ $ i.e. $\rm\ f_n = k\ f_m + f_{n-m}\equiv f_{n-m}\pmod{f_m}\:$ so

**THEOREM** $\: $  Let $\rm\ f_n\: $ be an integer sequence with $\rm\ f_{\:0} =\: 0\:\ $ and $\rm\ \: f_n\equiv f_{n-m}\ (mod\ f_m)\ $ for $\rm\: n > m\:$.  Then $\rm\:\ (f_n,f_m)\ =\ f_{(n,\:m)}\ \: $ where $\rm\ (i,\:j)\ $ denotes $\rm\ gcd(i,\:j)\:$.

**Proof** $\ $ By induction on  $\rm\:n + m\:$. The theorem is trivially true if $\rm\ n = m\ $ or $\rm\ n = 0\ $ or $\rm\: m = 0\:$.
So we may assume $\rm\:n > m > 0\:$.$\ $  Note $\rm\ (f_n,f_m)\: =\ (f_{n-m},f_m)\ $ follows from the hypothesis.
Since $\rm\:\ (n-m)+m \ <\ n+m\: ,\ $ induction yields $\rm\ \ (f_{n-m},f_m)\ =\ f_{(n-m,\:m)}\ =\ f_{(n,\:m)}\ \ $ **QED**

In particular $\rm\:(M_R,M_{RS}) = M_{(R,RS)} = M_R\ $ so $\rm\ M_R\:|\: M_{RS}$

See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/gcdbx-1-by-1-b-z-1-b-gcdx-y-z-1/11636#11636) for a conceptual proof exploiting the innate structure - an *order ideal*, and look up [divisibility sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence) to learn more about the essence of the matter.

Comment: Exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, thanks!