# infinite primes $p\equiv1\pmod n$ without cyclotomic polynomial

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Without cyclotomic polynomial, is there an elementary proof of  the following: for each integer $n>1$, there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p\equiv1\pmod n$ ?

please don't refer to [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), or analytic number theory. Thanks

Comment: For $n$ prime this can be done by taking a prime divisor $p$ of $2^n-1$. It follows that $n\mid p-1$. I'm not sure if this can be extended for composite $n$... I suppose you don't want to use Zsigmondy's theorem?

Comment: See Qiaochu's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/gcdbx-1-by-1-b-z-1-b-gcdx-y-z-1/11636#11636).You can prove a special case of the theorem using his answer.

Answer (score 2):

An elementary proof of this result is outlined in problem 36 on p. 108 of An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers by Niven, Zuckerman and Montgomery. That problem references the article by I. Niven and B. Powell "Primes in certain arithmetic progressions," Amer. Math. Monthly, 83 (1976), 467-469, as simplified by R.W. Johnson.

Comment: For the Niven book, I dont think you are referencing the right page. I am looking at the 4th edition right now and it is not there. However, I cannot find it. Maybe you mistyped?

Comment: @SandeepSilwal fifth edition

Comment: I was citing the fifth edition. The problem is from section 2.8 (Primitive Roots and Power Residues).