# What is $\gcd(a^2-1, a^3-1)$?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

What is $\gcd(a^2-1, a^3-1)$? Is it $1$? The exponents seem to follow the pattern of $\gcd(a, a+1)$.

Comment: Observe that if $a$ is odd then $2$ divides both, so answer cannot be $1$ in all cases. Moreover $a-1$ divides both, so..

Comment: Hint: use the Euclidean algorithm: $\!\bmod a^2-1\!:\ {a^2\equiv 1}\Rightarrow a^3-1\equiv a-1.\,$ Next $\bmod a-1\!:\ a\equiv 1\Rightarrow\, a^2-1\equiv 0,\,$ so the gcd = $(0,a-1) = a-1.\,$ Generally [$\gcd(a^n - 1, a^m - 1) = a^{\gcd(n, m)} - 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7473/242)

Comment: [More conceptually](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/11636/242) $\,d\mid a^2\!-\!1,a^3\!-\!1\iff \!\bmod d\!:\ a^2\equiv 1\equiv a^3\!\iff\! a\equiv 1\!\iff\! d\mid a\!-\!1,\,$ so $\,\{a^2\!-\!1,a^3\!-\!1\}\,$ and $\,\{\color{#c00}{a\!-\!1}\}$ have same set of common divisors $\,d\,$ so the same *greatest* common divisor, which clearly must be  $\,\color{#c00}{a\!-\!1}.\ $ This proof generalizes widely - see the linked post.

Answer (score 2):

$a^3-1 = (a-1)(a^2+a+1) = (a-1)(a(a+1)+1)$

$a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$

${\rm GCD}(a+1,a(a+1)+1)={\rm GCD}(a+1,1)=1$ so that ${\rm GCD}
(a^2-1,a^3-1)=a-1$