# Irrationality of square roots of nonsquare integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $n$ is a positive integer and is not a perfect square, how do you prove that $n^{1/2}$ is irrational?

Comment: do you  know how to prove $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational?

Comment: Yes, I do. But I was told to use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Comment: fine... once you prove that $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational for each prime $p$ then you can write $n$ as product of primes using fundamental theorem of arithmetic and then it is done!

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, you need an additional argument, since in general the product of two irrational numbers can be rational..

Comment: @Joachim : Of course additional argument is needed.. That is just a kind of hint!

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik ok nice =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $n$ is not a perfect square, there exists at least one prime number $p$ such that
$$n=p^\alpha q$$
where $q\in\mathbb N$ is coprime to $p$ and $\alpha\ge 1$ is odd.

Now, suppose that $n$ is a rational number, namely,
$$n^{1/2}=\frac{b}{a}$$
where $a,b$ are natural numbers and they are coprime to each other.

Then, we have
$$n=\frac{b^2}{a^2}\Rightarrow a^2n=b^2.$$

By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, this implies that the number of $p$ in the left hand side is odd, and that the number of $p$ in the right hand side is even. This is a contradiction.

Hence, $n^{1/2}$ is an irrational number.

Comment: And we know that the number of primes in the left hand side is odd because of what? I'm having serious trouble understanding the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Comment: @Courtney: Note that the number of the prime number of $p$ is odd in the left hand side, not all prime numbers. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, we have only one representation as $a={p_1}^{a_1}{p_2}^{a_2}\cdots {p_k}^{a_k}$ where $p_1\lt p_2\lt\cdots\lt p_k$ are prime numbers. So, $a^2={p_1}^{2a_1}\cdots{p_k}^{2a_k}.$ So, the number of each prime number of $a$ is even.

Comment: You mean "perfect square", not "perfect number".

Comment: @BillDubuque: Thanks for pointing it out. A typo. I know very little about "perfect number":)

Answer (score 5):

$\,n = (a/b)^2\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{a^2} = \color{#c00}nb^2.\, $ All primes occur to $\rm\color{#0a0}{even}$ power in the prime factorization of $\,\color{#0a0}{a^2},\,$ but, since $\,n\,$ is not a square, some prime occurs to $\color{#c00}{\rm odd}$ power in $\,\color{#c00}n,\,$ so odd power in $\,\color{#c00}nb^2\,\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$

**Remark** $ $ The above argument based upon the  $\rm\color{#0a0}{par}\color{#c00}{ity}$ of powers of primes depends *crucially* on FTA = Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic = *existence and uniqueness* of prime factorizations, so it is *essential* to mention the use of this strong property when presenting the proof (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4572/242) for much discussion on the required level of *rigor* in such proofs, which - alas - is often lacking).

We can also give proofs using closely related properties, e.g. the Rational Root Test (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/203305/242)) or Euclid's Lemma (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/11885/242)), or [Bezout's gcd identity.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) Below is a simple proof employing Bezout  that I discovered as a teenager (motivated by an idea of Dedekind).

**Theorem** $\quad \rm r = \sqrt{n}\;\;$ is integral if rational, $\:$ for $\:\rm n\in\mathbb{N}$

**Proof** $\ \ $ Note that $\rm\,\ \color{#0a0}{r = a/b},\ \ \gcd(a,b) = 1\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#C00}{ad\!-\!bc \,=\, \bf 1}\;$  for some $\:\rm c,d \in \mathbb{Z}\ $ by [Bezout.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)

$\rm\color{#C00}{That\,}$ and $\rm\: r^2\! = \color{orange}{\bf n}\:\Rightarrow\ \color{#0a0}{0\, =\, (a\!-\!br)}\, (c\!+\!dr) \ =\ ac\!-\!bd\color{orange}{\bf n} \:+\: \color{#c00}{\bf 1}\cdot r \ \Rightarrow\ r \in \mathbb{Z}\ \ \ $ **QED**

The proof [easily generalizes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4585/242) to roots of *monic* quadratic polynomials (and [to higher degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/91595/242)).

Comment: See also the "direct" method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1317951/242) which also works here (replace $2$ there by a prime that occurs to *even* power in $n)\ \ $

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2441234/242) for more about the key properties used in the proof.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Assuming the opposite, you have $\big(\frac ab\big)^2=\frac{a^2}{b^2}=n$ integer, so $b^2|a^2$ and $\frac ab$ not integer, so $b \nmid a$.

If $b \nmid a$, there is a prime factor $p$ of $a$ such that $p|a$ but $p \nmid b$. So $p|a^2$ and $p \nmid b^2$, a contradiction.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: @Courtney now is it OK?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $n=(a/b)^2$ for some positive integers $a$ and $b$. Let $p_1\lt p_2\lt\dots\lt p_k$ be all the prime divisors of $nab$. The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic tells you that, if $x_1,\dots,x_k$ and $y_1,\dots,y_k$ are nonnegative integers, then
$$p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}\cdots p_k^{x_k}=p_1^{y_1}p_2^{y_2}\cdots p_k^{y_k}\ \Rightarrow x_1=y_1,x_2=y_2,\dots,x_k=y_k.$$
Write $$n=p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}\cdots p_k^{x_k},\ a=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k},\ b=p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2}\cdots p_k^{\beta_k}$$
and use $n=(a/b)^2$ and the Fundamental Theorem to show that the $x_i$ are even, thus showing that $n$ is a perfect square.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is not a perfect square, then there is a prime $p$ dividing $n$ which occurs in the expansion of $n$ an *odd* number of times. From the equation $\sqrt n=a/b$ you get $b^2n=a^2$, in which that prime occurs evenly many times on the right, oddly many times on the left. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/309071), any [algebraic integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer) that is rational is an integer. Since all roots of $x^2-n=0$ are algebraic integers (since the lead coefficient of $x^2-n$ is $1$), if they are not integers, they are not rational. Thus, since $n$ is not a perfect square, $n$ is irrational.