# Proof verification: For all natural numbers, either $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational or $n$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I am attempting problem 19 from Chapter 2 of Spivak's Calculus book. It says the following:

A fundamental theorem about integers, which we will not prove here, states that [prime factorization] is unique, except for the order of the factors. Thus, for example, $28$ can never be written as a product of primes one of which is $3$, nor can it be written in a way that involves $2$ only once (now you should appreciate why 1 is not allowed as a prime).

Using this fact, prove that $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational unless $n=m^2$ for some natural number $m$.

My attempt goes as follows:

Let $n\in\mathbf{N}$ and suppose that $\sqrt{n}$ is rational. Then there are $a,b\in\mathbf{Z}$ with $b\neq 0$ such that $\sqrt{n}=a/b$. Note that $n>0$, so $a,b$ must be natural number. Then:

$n=a^2/b^2$

$n=\large\frac{(a_1\cdot a_2 \cdot ... \cdot a_{k_1})^2}{(b_1\cdot b_2 \cdot ... \cdot b_{k_2})^2}$

where $a_1,...,a_{k_1}$ and $b_1,..., b_{k_2}$ are the unique prime factors of $a$ and $b$ respectively. Since $n$ is a natural number then $k_2\leq k_1$ so $a/b$ must also be a natural number. Therefore, we can conclude that $n$ is a perfect square.

Comment: 1) Why must $a/b$ also be a natural number? 2) You are supposed to use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify *precisely* which step in the proof you question, and *why so*. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

Comment: You can find most all known proofs in the linked posts (and their links). Perusing them will help you understand how to complete your argument, e.g. comparing the the *parity* of prime powers in the *unique* prime factorization of $\,a^2=nb^2\,$
 as [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/639481/242)