# Proof by induction; $a^n$ divides $b^n$ implies $a$ divides $b$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, induction

I want to prove by induction that $a^n \mid b^n$ implies that $a \mid b$ holds for all integers $n\geq 1$.

Clearly for $n=1$ this is true, since if $a \mid b$, then $a \mid b$.

Suppose this is true for some $n = k$. Then $a^k \mid b^k$, so $a|b$.

$a^k \mid b^k$ means there exists some integer $m$ such that $b^k = ma^k$, and $a \mid b$ means there exists an integer $r$ such that $b=ra$.

Then we can multiply both sides of the above equality by any constant, namely $b$.

Then $b \cdot b^k = bma^k$

so $b^{k+1} = (ra)ma^k = rma^{k+1}$

which means that $a^{k+1} \mid b^{k+1}$ completing the induction step, and thus proving that for all integers $n \geq1$ the original statement holds.

Are there any logical holes in the proof?

Comment: What you've proved is that if $a^k\mid b^k$ and $a\mid b$, then $a^{k+1}\mid b^{k+1}$. This is, roughly speaking, the *converse* of what you want to prove. (Oh, I just saw this is an old post by a user who has not been active in a long time.)

Answer (score 6):

Let $a,b$ be integers and let $P(k)$ be the statement "$a^k \mid b^k$ implies $a \mid b$."  You are trying to prove by induction that $P(k)$ is true for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

You start out by proving the base case $P(1)$, which is fine.  Then you say "suppose this is true for some $k$," by which I mean you are supposing that $P(k)$ is true.  But *then* you say, "then $a^k \mid b^k$."  This does not follow from $P(k)$, since $P(k)$ says nothing about whether $a^k$ divides $b^k$ or not, just about what happens if it does.

What you need to do is show that if $P(k)$ is true, then $P(k+1)$ is also true.  Others have already talked about how to approach this, I just wanted to clarify a bit more what goes wrong with your attempt.

Comment: Nice explanation, Tara. +1

Answer (score 5):

That doesn't quite work. What you need to do is assume that for some $k\geq 1$ we have $a^k\mid b^k$ implies $a\mid b$ for all integers $a,b$. Now, suppose that $a^{k+1}\mid b^{k+1}$ for some $a,b$, and show that $a\mid b$. Given the inductive hypothesis, it will be enough for you to show that $a^k\mid b^k$.

Answer (score 5):

Inductive step should be $\,(P_k \Rightarrow Q)\Longrightarrow (P_{k+1}\Rightarrow Q),\,$ where $\,P_k := a^k\mid b^k,\ $ $\,Q := a\mid b$

But you proved $\ \ (P_k\ \,\&\,\ (P_k \Rightarrow Q)) \Longrightarrow\, P_{k+1},\,$ which is not equivalent.  Below are correct ways.

**Hint** $\, $ By *homogeneous reduction* (below) we may assume $\rm\,a,b\,$ coprime. Then it suffices to show that $\rm\,a\mid b^n\,\Rightarrow\,a\mid 1\,$ (so $\rm\,a\mid b).\,$ By Euclid's Lemma $\rm\ a\mid b(b^k)\,\Rightarrow\,a\mid b^k,\,$ so $\rm\, a\mid 1\,$ by induction.

**Remark** $\, $ Alternatively if $\rm\,(a,b)=1,\,$ and $\rm\,b^n/a^n = m\in\Bbb Z\,$ then $\rm\rm\, b/a\,$ is a rational root of $\rm\,x^n - m,\,$ so, by RRT = Rational Root Test,
$\rm\,b/a\in \Bbb Z,\,$ i.e. $\rm\,a\mid b.$

The first proof essentially uses an *inductive* extension of Euclid's Lemma: $ $ if $\rm\ a\ $ is coprime to all $\rm\,b_{\:\! i}\,$ then it is coprime to their product ([more *conceptually*:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62078/242) units (invertibles) $\rm\,b_{\:\! i}\bmod{a}\,$ are closed under multiplication). This is the key lemma at the core of the proof of RRT, so it too may be considered an *inductive* proof, since it invokes said inductive extension of Euclid's Lemma. If that doesn't satisfy whatever fuzzy notion of "true inductive proof" one employs, then [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/91595/23500) likely will. It is a little-known proof of monic RRT by *induction on degree.* As a particular case, one can prove cube-roots irrational by using irrationality proofs of square-roots!

[Homogeneous reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3471852/242) to the case $\rm\,\color{#c00}{a,b\ \text{coprime}}$ works more precisely as follows. Suppose that $\rm\,c = (A,B).\,$ Then $\rm\, A,B = ac,bc,\,$ where $\rm\,(a,b) = 1,\,$ hence

$$\rm A^n\mid B^n\Rightarrow\, a^n c^n \mid b^n c^n\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{a^n\mid b^n \Rightarrow a\mid b} \Rightarrow\, ac\mid bc\Rightarrow A\mid B$$

Thus the noncoprime case $\rm\, A^n\mid B^n\Rightarrow A\mid B\,$ follows from the coprime case $\rm\color{#c00}{a^n\mid b^n \Rightarrow a\mid b}$

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by Cameron Buie, it does not work. I would recommend you some other approach: let $M_a$ be the [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) of prime factors of $a$, that is, for any prime number $p$, $M_a(p) = \max\{k \in \mathbb{N} : p^k \mid a\}$. Now, $a \mid b \iff M_a \subset M_b$, however, $M_{a^k}(p) = k\cdot M_a(p)$, hence $M_{a^k} \subset M_{b^k}$ implies $M_a \subset M_b$.

Good luck!

Comment: This is a good approach, but doesn't very naturally lead to a proof by induction.