# Prove that $a^n$ divides $b^n$ implies that $a$ divides $b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility, solution-verification

> For $n \ge 1,$ and positive integers $a,b,$ show the following:
>
> $\rm (a)$ If $\gcd(a,b)=1,$ then $\gcd(a^n,b^n)=1.$
>
> $\rm (b)$ The relation $a^n\,|\,b^n$ implies that $a\,|\,b.$

This is a problem from *Elementary Number Theory* by David M. Burton. I was able to solve part $\rm(a)$ by expanding $(ax+by)^{2n-1}$ using binomial theorem and factoring. To solve part $\rm(b)$, I used Bezout's theorem along with the following hint given in the book:

> Put $d=\gcd(a,b)$ and write $a=rd,b=sd,$ where $\gcd(r,s) = 1.$ By part $\mathrm{(a)},\, \gcd(r^n,s^n)=1$. Show that $r=1$, whence $a=d.$

Before seeing the hint, I tried using mathematical induction as follows.

> Let $S$ denote the set of all positive integers $n$ for which $a^n\,|\,b^n\implies a\,|\,b.$ We observe that when $n=1,$ $a\,|\,b\implies a\,|\,b.$ This means that $1\in S.$
>
> Next, assume that $k\in S$ so that $a^k\,|\,b^k\implies a\,|\,b.$ Since $a^k\,|\,b^k,$ we can write $b^k$ as $$b^k=ma^k\tag1$$ for some integer $m$, and $b$ as $b=ra$ for some integer $r$.
>
> Multiplying $(1)$ by $b$ yields
>   $$\begin{align*}
> b^k\cdot b&=ma^k\cdot b,\\
> \text{or,}\quad \quad b^{k+1}&=ma^k\cdot ra,\\
> \text{or,}\quad\quad b^{k+1}&=mra^{k+1},\\
> \text{or,}\quad\quad b^{k+1}&=ca^{k+a},\tag{where $c=mr$}\\
> \text{i.e.,}\!\quad\quad a^{k+1}\,&|\,b^{k+1},
> \end{align*}$$ which is precisely the case for $n=k+1,$ putting $k+1\in S$ whenever $k\in S$. According to the first principle of finite induction, $S$ must be the set of all positive integers.
>
> $``\,\blacksquare"$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: I just found that my question is already asked [here][1] but the answers don't quite tell me the logical holes in my proof.

  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346034/proof-by-induction-an-divides-bn-implies-a-divides-b

Comment: How many chapters have you solved of Burton?

Comment: In fact the mistake is essentially the same as in the linked dupe, and the answers there already explain it (along with correct proofs). I elaborated a bit there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Next, assume that $k\in S$ so that $a^k\,|\,b^k\implies a\,|\,b.$ Since $a^k\,|\,b^k,$ we can write $b^k$ as $$b^k=ma^k\tag1$$ for some integer $m$, and $b$ as $b=ra$ for some integer $r$.

There's a mistake here. What you know is that a certain implication (namely "$a^k\,|\,b^k\implies a\,|\,b$") is true, and that's all you know from the inductive hypothesis. That means that *if* you know $a^k \mid b^k$, *then* you know that $a \mid b$, but it doesn't tell you that the antecedent is true. So when you write "Since $a^k \mid b^k$," you're assuming something that you don't know to be true, and your proof goes wrong.

This portion of the proof really should take the form

> Next, suppose that $k\in S$ so that $a^k\,|\,b^k\implies a\,|\,b.$ We now need
>   to show that $a^{k+1} \mid b^{k+1} \implies a \mid b$, i.e., that $k+1 \in S$. To show this, we assume that 
>   $$
> a^{k+1} \mid b^{k+1} \tag{*}
> $$
>   and will prove that $a \mid b$.

And *then* you have to write a proof, of course. Much of what you wrote is good stuff and can be recycled in some form. But that particular fragment --- "Since $a^k \mid b^k$" ---  was where your original proof went off the rails.

Comment: So we have to get $a^k\,|\,b^k$ from $a^{k+1}\,|\,b^{k+1}$ in order to prove that $a\,|\,b\,?$

Comment: (cont'd) because we have assumed $a^k\,|\,b^k\implies a\,|\,b$

Comment: That's at least one route to follow, yes. All I can really say is that to complete the proof, you should (1) assume $^{+1} \mid ^{+1}$, and (2) derive from this that $a \mid b$. Along the way, knowing that $a^k \mid b^k \implies a | b$ may prove helpful ... in which case the inductive structure is helping you ... or it may not.

Answer (score -1):

Write the prime decompositions of $a$ and $b$ as $$a=\prod_{i=i}^tp_i^{\mu _i},b=\prod_{i=i}^tp_i^{\lambda _i},$$. where $\mu_i, \lambda_i \text { are non-negative integers for }1 \le i \le t.$ The condition $a^n | b^n$ is equivalent to $n \mu_i \le n\lambda_i,1 \le i \le t,$ which implies $ \mu_i \le \lambda_i,1 \le i \le t,$ so $a|b.$

Comment: Why so many downvotes? Is this answer wrong? I don't think so. I give it a $+1$